# How do I POST JSON data with cURL?

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, curl, http-headers

I use Ubuntu and installed [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) on it. I want to test my Spring REST application with cURL. I wrote my POST code at the Java side. However, I want to test it with cURL. I am trying to post a JSON data. Example data is like this:

```
{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true}
```

I use this command:

```
curl -i \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" \
    -X POST -d "value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true \
    http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx
```

It returns this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1051
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2011 08:50:17 GMT
```

The error description is this:

> *The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().*

Tomcat log:
"POST /ui/webapp/conf/clear HTTP/1.1" 415 1051

What is the right format of the cURL command?

This is my Java side `PUT` code (I have tested GET and DELETE and they work):

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Configuration updateConfiguration(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestBody Configuration configuration) { //consider @Valid tag
    configuration.setName("PUT worked");
    //todo If error occurs response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    return configuration;
}
```

Comment: checkout the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16909742/spring-3-2-0-web-mvc-rest-api-and-json-2-post-requests-how-to-get-it-right-on/16909986#16909986) for spring 3.2.0 post requests.

Comment: There is a nice post [Using Curl For Ad Hoc Testing Of RESTful Microservices](http://goinbigdata.com/using-curl-for-ad-hoc-testing-of-restful-microservices/) which covers this with multiple examples.

Comment: By the way, it's better to minify json data before sending to server. Use [smart json](https://fe-tool.com/en-us/formatter/json) to is a better choice in 2023.

Answer (score 5608, accepted):

You need to set your content-type to application/json. But [`-d`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) (or `--data`) sends the Content-Type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, which is not accepted on Spring's side.

Looking at the [curl man page](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), I think you can use [`-H`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-H) (or `--header`):

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Full example:

```bash
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' \
  http://localhost:3000/api/login
```

(`-H` is short for `--header`, `-d` for `--data`)

Note that `-request POST` is *optional* if you use `-d`, as the `-d` flag implies a POST request.

---

On Windows, things are slightly different. See the comment thread.

Comment: @kamaci I don't think you need to remove -d, just use -H in addition.

Comment: I try that: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT" -X POST -d "value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true http://localhost:8080/ui/webapp/conf

Comment: @kamaci OK then I'm afraid I can't help you without having access to your server logs. I currently don't have access to any Spring MVC projects. I'd try to look for the http query path in your log file and continue from there. Perhaps you could append a relevant bit of the log to this question.

Comment: For windows, single quotes around json did not work and I ended up escaping double quotes. 

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"key1\": \"value1\" }" http://localhost:3000/api/method`

Comment: For me under Windows I needed to escape quotes using quotes in this format ```"{ """key1""": """value1""" }"```. Also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18314796/couchdb-curl-windows-command-line-invalid-json

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Yeah! It's ludicrous. At such moments I'm considering much more seriously moving to *nix system.

Comment: I've had issues with POST requests but solved it by capitalized "Application/json" so if you get a 415 error, check the capitalization.

Comment: if you use a model on @RequestBody, remember that it doesn't want a costructor

Comment: It is also possible to pipe the JSON data from `STDIN` by using `-d @-` as the `curl` option

Comment: `contentType` or `Content-Type`?

Comment: @FrozenFlame header names are title case with dashes, see [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17). Some frameworks like jquery accept headers in camelCase and translate those internally to Title-Dash, but curl doesn't afaik

Comment: I had to POST the data without 's around the {}'s. Then it worked. You'd think it'd be one standard wayto do it.

Comment: To use mixed single quotation and double quotation you can use git bash or some other third party provided terminal

Comment: Why does the windows version of curl require double-quotes around json data?? It's totally ridiculous

Comment: @Adam Tuttle Why does your comment have so many upvotes? With curl on ubuntu 14.04, you need `"Content-Type: application/json"`, not just `"application/json"`. This wasted a lot of my time...

Comment: @ostrokach sorry it wasted your time. syntax worked fine for me on OSX when I posted it (haven't retried). Guess it is/was just a platform difference. I imagine the upvotes are from people that it helped.

Comment: Can you put a little note that this might not work on windows? Ctrl-F "Windows" below.

Comment: @JayKeegan I added a little note but I'm not going to pollute my post with that strange syntax

Comment: I face even more strange behaviour when calling this curl command by java `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` method, in linux I must remove the double quotes. anybody knows why?

Comment: Just like `-d` or `--data` defaults to using `POST`, so does the `--data-urlencode` option.

Comment: I was using -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' on linux which shell is UTF-8 .., but strangely removing the charset parameter solved my problem as well.

Comment: On windows, I managed to single quote the whole parameter, leaving the original json with double quotes, like the "Full example" above:
`-d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}'`

Comment: ```| python -m json.tool```
add this pipe to get json output in readable format

Comment: When I am trying to use the same format in Linux, I am getting "no data provided" error.

Comment: Windows cmd prompt: the triple quotes in the JSON was step one for me, but step two was to realize that the API example I was working from used single quotes around the Content-Type. Once I changed everything to double quotes, I was golden.

Comment: haven't seen this anywhere, but the only thing that worked for me (powershell) was to say `-d '{\"message\": false}'`

Comment: Adding "-c cookies.txt" to store the session cookie for use in request that require authenticate would be good to include in the command, though it is optional.

Answer (score 735):

Try to put your data in a file, say `body.json` and then use

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @body.json http://localhost:8080/ui/webapp/conf
```

Comment: checkout [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16909986/2210206) on how use CURL and what does different errors mean.

Comment: You probably should use the `--data-binary` option instead of `--data`. One would expect that the client sends the data as-is, but `--data` strips CR und LF from the input.

Comment: Using cUrl with inline json Strings seems to be a nightmare. There's the need to scape the double quote character. Going with a file like this is nicer.

Comment: It's important to add an `@` character before the name of the file, otherwise it won't work. I just spent 20 minutes banging my head at this crap...

Comment: This way you can also run a JSON lint on the file to see if there's an error in parsing the JSON.

Comment: On Windows, you need double quotes around the filename "@body.json"

Comment: First, THANK YOU, you just saved me days of headache. Also, I'm using Windows 10 and was able to get the @file_name.json without needing quotes. I put the JSON query into a file and used English/Spanish/Chinese in my file query (so no need to set UTF). Here is my final call: `curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <key>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary @body.json "<endpoint>"`

Comment: Having a separate file for every jason command to pass to --data sounds like a nightmare. Couldn't you just use a here string (`<<<`) which is a variable assigned with multi-line indented JSON text in "pretty" format?

Comment: where to place the  `.json` file?  In the same folder of curl or some other location?

Comment: @Moeez - yes same folder (unless you want to write the path to the file)

Comment: This is the ONLY way I could find that ran in a simple bash script without the need for installing anything else. Kudos.

Answer (score 155):

For Windows, having a single quote for the `-d` value did not work for me, but it did work after changing to double quote. Also I needed to escape double quotes inside curly brackets.

That is, the following did not work:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key":"val"}' http://localhost:8080/appname/path
```

But the following worked:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"key\":\"val\"}" http://localhost:8080/appname/path
```

Comment: FYI - looks like you're missing a closing double quote around the json body

Comment: For me on Windows, the " around the data does not work, no quotes works instead

Comment: If you're using PowerShell, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36004654/158074) answer.

Comment: For improved quote-handling, and many other reasons, stop using the ancient/weak cmd.exe and try one of the improved shells like Git-Bash from https://gitforwindows.org/ site. (Highly recommended, even if you don't use Git.)

Comment: yep, quoting behaviour is a [mess](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1995) in pwsh. But it should be fixed in pwsh 7.3, in 7.2 you can run `Enable-ExperimentalFeature PSNativeCommandArgumentPassing` to not have to escape this quotes

Answer (score 120):

You might find [resty](https://github.com/micha/resty) useful:

It's a wrapper round CURL which simplifies command line REST requests. You point it to your API endpoint, and it gives you PUT and POST commands (Examples adapted from the homepage).

```
resty http://127.0.0.1:8080/data #Sets up resty to point at your endpoing
GET /blogs.json                  #Gets http://127.0.0.1:8080/data/blogs.json
                                 #Put JSON
PUT /blogs/2.json '{"id" : 2, "title" : "updated post", "body" : "This is the new."}'
                                 # POST JSON from a file
POST /blogs/5.json < /tmp/blog.json
```

Also, it's often still necessary to add the Content Type headers. You can do this once, though, to set a default, of add configuration files per-method per-site: [Setting default RESTY options](https://github.com/micha/resty#setting-the-default-curl-options)

Answer (score 110):

It worked for me using:

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":100}' http://localhost/api/postJsonReader.do
```

It was happily mapped to the Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postJsonReader", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String processPostJsonData(@RequestBody IdOnly idOnly) throws Exception {
        logger.debug("JsonReaderController hit! Reading JSON data!"+idOnly.getId());
        return "JSON Received";
}
```

`IdOnly` is a simple [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) with an id property.

Answer (score 81):

You can use [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) to convert to CURL:

[image]

[image]

Note:

The latest [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) version has some UI upgrades and now the code link is available in the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: The best answer, saved a lot of time, thanks :)

Comment: This is a nice way for beginners to understand mapping from a UI tool like this to the curl command, but it's not sustainable in the long term as another dependency to learn and maintain

Answer (score 65):

As an example, create a JSON file, *params.json*, and add this content to it:

```
[
    {
        "environment": "Devel",
        "description": "Machine for test, please do not delete!"
    }
]
```

Then you run this command:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @params.json -u your_username:your_password http://localhost:8000/env/add_server
```

Comment: Pro tip: add this line to your `~/.curlrc` file: `--header Content-Type:Application/JSON`

Answer (score 50):

I just run into the same problem. I could solve it by specifying

```
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 45):

This worked well for me.

```
curl -X POST --data @json_out.txt http://localhost:8080/
```

Where,

`-X` Means the HTTP verb.

`--data` Means the data you want to send.

Comment: The `-X POST` is redundant in this example

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer but at least it's instructive for begginers.

Comment: Better have transparent but redundant code, rather than non-transparent code. I also prefer `--data` instead of `-d`. It depends on how good the team is with Bash overall, but definitely easier for Bash beginners, and people who don't use it on a daily basis.

Answer (score 41):

You can use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) with its intuitive GUI to assemble your `cURL` command.

1. Install and Start **Postman**
2. Type in your URL, Post Body, Request Headers etc. pp.
3. Click on `Code`
4. Select `cURL` from the drop-down list
5. copy & paste your `cURL` command

*Note: There are several options for automated request generation in the drop-down list, which is why I thought my post was neccessary in the first place.*

Comment: Didn't realize that feature was included in Postman.  Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 41):

## TL;DR:

Use the holy trinity, [`jo`](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) + [`curl`](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/02/02/curl-dash-dash-json/) + [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (or [`fx`](https://github.com/antonmedv/fx)):

```
jo value=30 type="Tip 3" targetModule="Target 3" configurationGroup=null name="Configuration Deneme 3" description=null identity="Configuration Deneme 3" | \
curl --json @- \
    -X POST \
    http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx | \
jq
```

This will cover necessary headers that were missing: no need to explicitly define the `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers.

## The new curl way with --json

Early March 2022, `curl` released [a new command line parameter](https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2022/02/02/curl-dash-dash-json/) `--json` with version 7.82.0. This allows for a shortcut to send through JSON and eliminating the need to define the `Content-Type` **that you had missing** and `Accept` headers as these are automatically assumed, hence reducing risk of mistakes:

```
curl --json '{"tool": "curl"}' https://example.com/
```

But wait... there is more. Instead of defining the json parameter as a string to the `curl` command line, use the [nifty `jo` CLI tool](https://jpmens.net/2016/03/05/a-shell-command-to-create-json-jo/) to define JSON as series of key value pairs and pipe the output through curl. Using `jo` only to define your JSON, it works this way:

```
 > jo -p value=30 type="Tip 3" targetModule="Target 3" configurationGroup=null name="Configuration Deneme 3" description=null identity="Configuration Deneme 3"
version=0 systemId=3 active=true
{
   "value": 30,
   "type": "Tip 3",
   "targetModule": "Target 3",
   "configurationGroup": null,
   "name": "Configuration Deneme 3",
   "description": null,
   "identity": "Configuration Deneme 3",
   "version": 0,
   "systemId": 3,
   "active": true
}
```

Let's showcase this now with a similar `curl` command of yours but without extra headers and using `jo` + `jq` for nice output:

```
jo value=30 type="Tip 3" targetModule="Target 3" configurationGroup=null name="Configuration Deneme 3" description=null identity="Configuration Deneme 3" | \
curl --json @- \
    -X POST \
    http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx | \
jq
```

## Example with a free API

[Using a free mock API](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) for demonstration:

```
> jo title="Blog Post" body="lorem ipsum" userId=33 | \
curl --json @- \
    -X POST \
    https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts | \
jq
```

The output has a pretty format thanks to `jq`:

```
{
  "title": "Blog Post",
  "body": "lorem ipsum",
  "userId": 33,
  "id": 101
}
```

Comment: If you installed `curl` via `brew`, you can also `brew upgrade curl` to get 7.82.0

Comment: Seems jo doesn't like a value of @ (example: DNS records) replace with \@ in that case.

Answer (score 36):

[HTTPie](https://httpie.org/) is a recommended alternative to `curl` because you can do just

```
http POST http://example.com/some/endpoint name=value name1=value1
```

It speaks JSON by default and will handle both setting the necessary header for you as well encoding data as valid JSON. There is also:

```
Some-Header:value
```

for headers, and

```
name==value
```

for query string parameters. If you have a large chunk of data, you can also read it from a file have it be JSON encoded:

```
field=@file.txt
```

Comment: I pray for this to be a standard - at least in terms of being available / preinstalled on each server.

Comment: Also, it would be great if `httpie` supported spilling out the `curl` formatted command, for the situation when `httpie` is not available on a specific host.

Answer (score 33):

Using CURL Windows, try this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"firstName\": \"blablabla\",\"lastName\": \"dummy\",\"id\": \"123456\"}" http-host/_ah/api/employeeendpoint/v1/employee
```

Answer (score 26):

Use -d option to add payload

```sh
curl -X POST \
http://<host>:<port>/<path> \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
"foo": "bar",
"lorem": "ipsum"
}'
```

In addition:

use -X POST to use POST method

use -H 'Accept: application/json' to add accept type header

use -H 'Content-Type: application/json' to add content type header

Comment: I tried to use it but getting {"errors":["no data provided"]} error.

Comment: @Suresh try `curl`'s `-v` switch to get more details. The service you are hitting may be only handling certain content-type values.

Answer (score 25):

This worked well for me, additionally using BASIC authentication:

```
curl -v --proxy '' --basic -u Administrator:password -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
        --data-binary '{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true}'
        http://httpbin.org/post
```

Of course, you should never use BASIC authentication without SSL and a checked certificate.

I ran into this again today, using Cygwin's cURL 7.49.1 for Windows... And when using `--data` or `--data-binary` with a JSON argument, cURL got confused and would interpret the `{}` in the JSON as a URL template. Adding a `-g` argument to turn off cURL globbing fixed that.

See also *[Passing a URL with brackets to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333920/passing-a-url-with-brackets-to-curl)*.

Answer (score 25):

If you're testing a lot of JSON send/responses against a RESTful interface, you may want to check out the [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) plug-in for Chrome (which allows you to manually define web service tests) and its Node.js-based [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro) command-line companion (which allows you to automate tests against "collections" of Postman tests.)  Both free and open!

Answer (score 22):

You could also put your JSON content in a file and pass it to curl using the `--upload-file` option via standard input, like this:

```
echo 'my.awesome.json.function({"do" : "whatever"})' | curl -X POST "http://url" -T -
```

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @./my_json_body.txt http://192.168.1.1/json
```

Answer (score 19):

I had the issue of:

> curl -X POST http://your-server-end-point -H "Content-Type: application/json"
> -d @path-of-your-json-file.json

See, I did everything right. **Only one thing** - I missed "@" before the JSON file path.

I found one relevant go-to document on Internet - *[Common Options](https://gist.github.com/subfuzion/08c5d85437d5d4f00e58)*.

Answer (score 18):

Here is another way to do it, if you have dynamic data to be included.

```
#!/bin/bash

version=$1
text=$2
branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
repo_full_name=$(git config --get remote.origin.url | sed 's/.*:\/\/github.com\///;s/.git$//')
token=$(git config --global github.token)

generate_post_data()
{
  cat <<EOF
{
  "tag_name": "$version",
  "target_commitish": "$branch",
  "name": "$version",
  "body": "$text",
  "draft": false,
  "prerelease": false
}
EOF
}

echo "Create release $version for repo: $repo_full_name branch: $branch"
curl --data "$(generate_post_data)" "https://api.github.com/repos/$repo_full_name/releases?access_token=$token"
```

Answer (score 13):

I am using the below format to test with a web server.

```
use -F 'json data'
```

Let's assume this JSON dict format:

```
{
    'comment': {
        'who':'some_one',
        'desc' : 'get it'
    }
}
```

#### Full example

```
curl -XPOST your_address/api -F comment='{"who":"some_one", "desc":"get it"}'
```

Comment: I can't see how this could possibly be a general-purpose answer. Your server may be configured to handle this strange format, but YMMV.

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me for on Windows 10:

```
curl -d "{"""owner""":"""sasdasdasdasd"""}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X  PUT http://localhost:8080/api/changeowner/CAR4
```

Answer (score 9):

I made a tool called [fetcher](https://pranayrauthu.github.io/fetcher/#/curl) for this. It can send requests and format curl snippets:

Here's an example:

[image]

Example output:

```
curl -XGET -H "Accept: application/json" -d "{\"value\":\"30\",\"type\":\"Tip 3\",\"targetModule\":\"Target 3\",\"configurationGroup\":null,\"name\":\"Configuration Deneme 3\",\"description\":null,\"identity\":\"Configuration Deneme 3\",\"version\":0,\"systemId\":3,\"active\":true}" "http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx"
```

Comment: Request/tip: URL links should be clearly spelled out. (Not just mysterious "click here.") Especially for self-promotion of your homemade tool.

Answer (score 8):

For PowerShell I've used:

```
curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "@content.json" http://localhost:8080/appname/path
```

Where *content.json* was the name of the JSON file on my local containing the request, and `curl.exe` instead of just `curl` not to use the alias for *[Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest)*.

Or if you want to specify directly the JSON:

```
curl.exe -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"xyz\"}' http://localhost:8080/appname/path
```

Answer (score 4):

`--json <data>` Sends the specified JSON data in a POST request to the HTTP server.

curl 7.82.0+

```bash
# Send a basic JSON object
curl --json '{"name":"xyz","breed":"xyz","age":100}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/cats

# letter @, read the data from a file
curl --json @cat.txt http://127.0.0.1:3000/cats

# letter -, read the data from stdin
echo '{"name":"xyz","breed":"xyz","age":100}' | curl --json @- http://127.0.0.1:3000/cats
```

curl 7.82.0-

```bash
curl -X POST --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":"xyz","breed":"xyz","age":100}' http://127.0.0.1:3000/cats
```

- https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--json

Answer (score 3):

- *-H* to send something like content-type or an authentication token in the header
- *-d* here adds your data
- finally add a site link

***Note***: Don't forget to add an authentication token (if you have) for authentication credentials

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Token 2de403987713595a7955a9b4655b9e206d4294b3' -d '{"title":"Post test with curl", "body": "test body"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/feeds/
```

Answer (score 3):

To POST JSON data with cURL, you should use the `-d` flag with the data enclosed in single quotes and specify the content type as `application/json` using the `-H` flag. Here's the corrected cURL command:

```bash
curl -i \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST -d '{"value":"30","type":"Tip 3","targetModule":"Target 3","configurationGroup":null,"name":"Configuration Deneme 3","description":null,"identity":"Configuration Deneme 3","version":0,"systemId":3,"active":true}' \
    http://localhost:8080/xx/xxx/xxxx
```

Explanation of changes:

1. Added `-H "Content-Type: application/json"` to specify that you are sending JSON data in the request body.
2. Enclosed the JSON data in single quotes (`'`) to ensure that it is treated as a single argument by cURL.
3. Wrapped the JSON data with `{}` to create a valid JSON object.

This should resolve the "415 Unsupported Media Type" error, and your Spring REST application should be able to accept the JSON data correctly.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. `JSON parse error: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')]`

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Anand Rockzz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl/57369772#57369772), here is what I did to this on [GitHub Actions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub#Scope). It was a bit tricky due to the `EOF` tag.

My goal was to send an HTTP call once a Vercel deployment was finished (similar to a webhook).

This [real-world example](https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/v2-mst-aptd-at-lcz-sty/.github/workflows/deploy-vercel-staging.yml#L263-L358) might help other people.

```
send-webhook-callback-once-deployment-ready:
  name: Invoke webhook callback url defined by the customer (Ubuntu 18.04)
  runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
  needs: await-for-vercel-deployment
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1 # Get last commit pushed - See https://github.com/actions/checkout
    - name: Expose GitHub slug/short variables # See https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action#exposed-github-environment-variables
      uses: rlespinasse/github-slug-action@v3.x # See https://github.com/rlespinasse/github-slug-action
    - name: Expose git environment variables and call webhook (if provided)
      # Workflow overview:
      #  - Resolves webhook url from customer config file
      #  - If a webhook url was defined, send a
      run: |
        MANUAL_TRIGGER_CUSTOMER="${{ github.event.inputs.customer}}"
        CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY="${MANUAL_TRIGGER_CUSTOMER:-$(cat vercel.json | jq --raw-output '.build.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CUSTOMER_REF')}"

        VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK=$(cat vercel.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json | jq --raw-output '.build.env.VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK')

        # Checking if a webhook url is defined
        if [ -n "$VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK" ]; then
          # Run script that populates git-related variables as ENV variables
          echo "Running script populate-git-env.sh"
          . ./scripts/populate-git-env.sh

          echo "Resolved git variables:"
          echo "'GIT_COMMIT_SHA': $GIT_COMMIT_SHA"
          echo "'GIT_COMMIT_REF': $GIT_COMMIT_REF"
          echo "'GIT_COMMIT_TAGS': $GIT_COMMIT_TAGS"

          # Generates JSON using a bash function - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57369772/2391795
          # "End Of File" must be at the beginning of the line with no space/tab before or after - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12909284/2391795
          # But, when executed by GitHub Action, it must be inside the "run" section instead
          generate_post_data() {
            cat <<EOF
          {
            "MANUAL_TRIGGER_CUSTOMER": "${MANUAL_TRIGGER_CUSTOMER}",
            "CUSTOMER_REF": "${CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY}",
            "STAGE": "staging",
            "GIT_COMMIT_SHA": "${GIT_COMMIT_SHA}",
            "GIT_COMMIT_REF": "${GIT_COMMIT_REF}",
            "GIT_COMMIT_TAGS": "${GIT_COMMIT_TAGS}",
            "GITHUB_REF_SLUG": "${GITHUB_REF_SLUG}",
            "GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG": "${GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG}",
            "GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG": "${GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG}",
            "GITHUB_EVENT_REF_SLUG": "${GITHUB_EVENT_REF_SLUG}",
            "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG": "${GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG}",
            "GITHUB_REF_SLUG_URL": "${GITHUB_REF_SLUG_URL}",
            "GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG_URL": "${GITHUB_HEAD_REF_SLUG_URL}",
            "GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG_URL": "${GITHUB_BASE_REF_SLUG_URL}",
            "GITHUB_EVENT_REF_SLUG_URL": "${GITHUB_EVENT_REF_SLUG_URL}",
            "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG_URL": "${GITHUB_REPOSITORY_SLUG_URL}",
            "GITHUB_SHA_SHORT": "${GITHUB_SHA_SHORT}"
          }
        EOF
          }

          echo "Print generate_post_data():"
          echo "$(generate_post_data)"

          echo "Calling webhook at '$VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK'"
          echo "Sending HTTP request (curl):"
          curl POST \
            "$VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK" \
            -vs \
            --header "Accept: application/json" \
            --header "Content-type: application/json" \
            --data "$(generate_post_data)" \
            2>&1 | sed '/^* /d; /bytes data]$/d; s/> //; s/< //'

          # XXX See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225157/2391795
          # -vs - add headers (-v) but remove progress bar (-s)
          # 2>&1 - combine stdout and stderr into single stdout
          # sed - edit response produced by curl using the commands below
          #   /^* /d - remove lines starting with '* ' (technical info)
          #   /bytes data]$/d - remove lines ending with 'bytes data]' (technical info)
          #   s/> // - remove '> ' prefix
          #   s/< // - remove '< ' prefix

        else
          echo "No webhook url defined in 'vercel.$CUSTOMER_REF_TO_DEPLOY.staging.json:.build.env.VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK' (found '$VERCEL_DEPLOYMENT_COMPLETED_WEBHOOK')"
        fi
```

Answer (score 2):

The *issue is here*:

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
```

Server Login can't interpret the Media Type of this request, so it is parsing it as text/html

> The media type of any resource is declared in the Content-Type
> property of the request header

"accept" ... header will fail this request, so the following is required for any JSON request to be sent i.e. content-type

```
-H 'content-type: application/json'
```

Suppose data and URL are something like this

> {"email": "admin@admin.com","password": "123456"}

> http://localhost:5000/api/login

Then in Linux

```
curl  http://localhost:5000/api/login  -H 'content-type: application/json'  -d '{"email": "user@admin.com", "password": "123456"}'
```

In Windows (single quotes around parameters will not work)

```
curl  http://localhost:5000/api/login  -H "content-type: application/json"  -d "{\"email\": \"user@admin.com\", \"password\": \"123456\"}"
```

-X POST key is not required when -d {.....} is present in command.

For a [PUT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request:

```
-X PUT
```

Answer (score 2):

You can [cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)) the contents of a JSON file to `curl` via the `--data-raw` parameter.

`curl 'https://api.com/route' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "$(cat ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | grep -v '^\s*//')"`

Note: comments in the JSON file are filtered out via `grep -v '^\s*//'`

You can also pass the data to `curl` via [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) using `grep` or `cat`.

`grep -v '^\s*//' ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | curl 'https://api.com/route' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`

`cat ~/.json/payload-2022-03-03.json | grep -v '^\s*//' | curl 'https://api.com/route' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @-`

Answer (score 2):

simple is that

```
curl -X POST https://localhost:3000/ 
   -H "Content-Type: application/json"
   -d '{"productId": 123456, "quantity": 100}'
```

Answer (score 0):

below code works for me.

I was using [Sample data api](https://sampledataapi.com)

```
curl -X POST --data @json_out.txt https://sampledataapi.com/API/login
```

Here the explanation

```
-X Means the HTTP verb.
--data Means the data you want to send.
```