# Passing a URL with brackets to curl

Tags: curl

If I try to pass a URL to curl that contains brackets, it fails with an error:

```
$ curl 'http://www.google.com/?TEST[]=1'
curl: (3) [globbing] illegal character in range specification at pos 29
```

However, if I escape both brackets, it appears to work:

```
$ curl 'http://www.google.com/?TEST\[\]=1'
```

How do I fix this? Is there an argument that will escape URLs automatically, or a description of the characters that need to be escaped before passing to curl?

Answer (score 632, accepted):

Add `-g` to your command:

```
-g, --globoff
      This option switches off the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can
      specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having curl itself interpret them.
      Note that these letters are not normal legal URL contents but they should be encoded
      according to the URI standard.

      Example:
       curl -g "https://example.com/{[]}}}}"
```

[curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-g](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-g)

Comment: For me, it didn't work. I had to add a \ before each square bracket

Comment: @jesusperaltac Same for me, with macOS

Comment: For me it worked - on OS X High Sierr, curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0.

Comment: @Jean  @jesusperaltac  for me it works on windows if the command is `curl -L -o <local_file_name> -g <url>`

Comment: Worked for me CentOS 7.1.  Curl version 7.29.0 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.29.0)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 and the -g did not work for me either. I had to use \ in front of every bracket and brace.

Answer (score 21):

[Globbing](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) uses brackets, hence the need to escape them with a slash `\`. Alternatively, the following command-line switch will disable globbing:

`--globoff` (or the short-option version: `-g`)

Ex:

```
curl --globoff https://www.google.com?test[]=1
```

Answer (score 3):

In the [documentation](https://curl.se/docs/url-syntax.html) it is written:

> globbing letters
>
> The curl command line tool supports "globbing" of URLs. It means that you can create ranges and lists using [N-M] and {one,two,three} sequences. The letters used for this ([]{}) are reserved in RFC 3986 and can therefore not legitimately be part of such a URL.
>
> They are however not reserved or special in the WHATWG specification, so globbing can mess up such URLs. Globbing can be turned off for such occasions (using --globoff).

It means that you should do percent-encoding for [reserved/special characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2) (`:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`) to avoid their special interpretation. To do so you put percent sign (`%`) and hex value of character in [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). For example:

| Symbol | Encoded Value |
| --- | --- |
| `[` | `%5B` |
| `]` | `%5D` |
| `{` | `%7B` |
| `}` | `%7D` |

`curl` doesn't expect reserved/special characters in URL and these four symbols are used to generate multiple URLs (*globbing* operation):

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TEST[a-c]=1
```

will equivalent to

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTa=1
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTb=1
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTc=1
```

and

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TEST{a,c,e}=1
```

will equivalent to

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTa=1
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTc=1
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TESTe=1
```

If you want to disable globbing operation:

- encode them:

  ```
  $ curl http://localhost:8080/?TEST%5Ba-c%5D=1
  $ curl http://localhost:8080/?TEST%7Ba,c,e%7d=1
  ```

  For `zsh` (default shell on Mac OS X) you must escape `?` as well. Thus for both `bash` and `zsh` shells:

  ```
  $ curl http://localhost:8080/\?TEST%5Ba-c%5D=1
  $ curl http://localhost:8080/\?TEST%7Ba,c,e%7d=1
  ```
- or use [`-g`/`--globoff`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-g) option:

  ```
  $ curl -g http://localhost:8080/?TEST[a-c]=1
  $ curl -g http://localhost:8080/?TEST{a,c,e}=1  # not enough, see note below
  ```

  ☝ In last example there is a caveat: globbing may be done by `bash` and `zsh` shell. To avoid globbing by shell:

  - either escape characters putting reverse slash (`\`) (don't forget about escaping `?` for `zsh` shell):

    ```
    $ curl -g http://localhost:8080/\?TEST\[a-c\]=1
    $ curl -g http://localhost:8080/\?TEST\{a,c,e\}=1
    ```
  - or put URL in quotes (single or double):

    ```
    $ curl -g 'http://localhost:8080/?TEST[a-c]=1'
    $ curl -g 'http://localhost:8080/?TEST{a,c,e}=1'
    ```

☝ Also be aware that empty square brackets (`[]`) don't lead to globbing in `curl`:

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/?TEST[]=1'
```

will request `/?TEST[]=1`.

This is not true for empty curly brackets (`{}`):

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:8080/?TEST{}=1'
curl: (3) empty string within braces in URL position 29:
http://localhost:8080/?TEST{}=1
                            ^
```

they must contain at least one string.

---

P.S. You may test on `docker` (press `Ctrl+C` to quit):

```
$ docker run --rm -p 8080:80 -it nginx
```

and run `curl` against it in separate terminal:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/?TEST[a-c]=1
```

In logs you should see generate URL for request:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2023:09:21:53 +0000] "GET /?TESTa=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "curl/7.86.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2023:09:21:53 +0000] "GET /?TESTb=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "curl/7.86.0" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2023:09:21:53 +0000] "GET /?TESTc=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 615 "-" "curl/7.86.0" "-"
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me, I have to replace all opening/closing brackets with `%5B` and `%5D`.

`[ ---> %5B` and for

`] ---> %5D`

My initial curl url was like this this

`https://test.com/computer/agent1/api/json?pretty=true&tree=executors[currentExecutable[url]]`

Now I am using like this

`https://test.com/computer/agent1/api/json?pretty=true&tree=executors%5BcurrentExecutable%5Burl%5D%5D`

Comment: This was the only solution working for me with MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error though there were no (obvious) brackets in my URL, and in my situation the --globoff command will not solve the issue.

For example (doing this on on mac in iTerm2):

```
for endpoint in $(grep some_string output.txt); do curl "http://1.2.3.4/api/v1/${endpoint}" ; done
```

I have grep aliased to "grep --color=always". As a result, the above command will result in this error, with some_string highlighted in whatever colour you have grep set to:

```
curl: (3) bad range in URL position 31:
http://1.2.3.4/api/v1/lalalasome_stringlalala
```

The terminal was transparently translating the [colour\codes]some_string[colour\codes] into the expected no-special-characters URL when viewed in terminal, but behind the scenes the colour codes were being sent in the URL passed to curl, resulting in brackets in your URL.

Solution is to not use match highlighting.