# Curl parameter array not working

Tags: arrays, curl

When i try to filter posts based on the filter/keyword array the parameter is not found/NULL

```
curl -H "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer TOKEN" -X GET http://test.local:10088/posts -d "filter[keyword]=test" -v
```

The same request in a browser will return "test"

```
http://test.local:10088/posts?filter[keyword]=test
```

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-d is for POST data. Yours is a GET, just add your "filter[keyword]=test" parameters as part of the URL without the -d parameter.

Also, just in case you are running into a character escaping problem with brackets and other chars, have a look at this: [Passing a URL with brackets to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333920/passing-a-url-with-brackets-to-curl)

Comment: I already tried that and then the terminal only displays a ">"

Comment: I suspect that could be because you need to escape the [ and ] from the command line and perhaps the = as well. I'll try it later but I comment so you can look into it too.

Comment: updated my answer to includd character-escaping info.

Comment: Thanks! it was the escaping, the correct way = `curl -H "AUTHORIZATION: Bearer TOKEN" -X GET http://test.local:10088/posts?filter\[keyword\]=test -v -g`

Answer (score 0):

Use quotes for URL:

```
curl -X GET "http://test.local:10088/posts?filter[keyword]=test"
```