# hangouts api json not working inside batch script

Tags: json, api, batch-file, chat, google-hangouts

This command works fine if I paste into a command window directly:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"test\"}" --url "https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/[removed]/messages?key=[removed]&token=[removed]"
```

yet when I execute this from within a batch file, I receive the following:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I've tried every permutation of escaping the quotes in the `json` data statement with no luck.

Comment: Maybe try add [-g switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333999/5403468) ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - it's not even illustrated in the sample I posted as I had removed the URL.  The issue related to a % symbol I had in the URL - in a batch script these need to be escaped by entering %% instead of %.  Hope this saves someone the hours I wasted on such a stupid mistake.  Thanks to those who reviewed or responded - sorry to have wasted your time  :-(