# How to get data in php curl with square brackets query?

Tags: php, curl, square-bracket

I try to get data with libcurl in PHP and my query, value in query, contains query brackets

```
?conditions[prs_id]=7&conditions[date]=[2019-03-26 TO 2019-04-03]&page=1&limit=1
```

When I send this with Postman I get object, but with curl i get error 400 which says this is bad request.
but with

```
?conditions[prs_id]=7&conditions[date]=2019-03-26
```

I get answer and requested objects. 
So The problem is with value with brackets `[2019-03-26 TO 2019-04-03]`

I tried with url encoding, changing brackets to url codes but it won't worked.

How to properly send this with libcurl in PHP? in Postman works

Comment: Postman can give you the answer. You can use the show code function and select PHP > curl

Comment: Might be due to how the spaces get encoded - `+` or `%20`, maybe the receiver only likes one specific version.

Comment: Could you tell me how? I'm not very fluent in this field.

Comment: Already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333920/passing-a-url-with-brackets-to-curl

Comment: no, this in not answer for my question, I'm using libcurl not cURL

Comment: Just click the code link: https://s3.amazonaws.com/postman-static-getpostman-com/postman-docs/58525940.png

Comment: This is a hint, thanks. so brackets in value aren't encoded `conditions[psr_id]=7&amp; conditions[date]=[2019-03-26 TO 2019-04-03]&amp; page=1&amp; limit=1 HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `urlencode()` function in the query. I am not sure it will work or not but you can give it a try

Comment: the problem with urlencode() was becuse I encoded full query and It didn't work. Now I encode only part of data `"%5B2019-03-26+TO+2019-04-03%5D"` and this work

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to build query params in url `http_build_query`