# Not getting results from docker api list tasks with filters

Tags: docker, curl

I am trying to find list of tasks using docker api. I am running the command as below:

```
curl -v --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 10 --retry 5 'https://${DOCKER_URL}/tasks?filters={%22service%22:{%22test1%22}}' | jq ..
```

When i run this I get curl:

```
 (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 51
```

I have tried other way also as below:

```
curl -s -q --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 10 --retry 5 --data-urlencode 'filters={"service":["test1"]}' https://${DOCKER_URL}/tasks
{"message":"page not found"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "-g" as a parameter to curl (see also [Passing a URL with brackets to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333920/passing-a-url-with-brackets-to-curl)), and use without encoding, like:

```
curl -g -v --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 10 --retry 5 \
  'http://127.0.0.1:2375/tasks?filters={"service":["test1"]}' | jq .
```

Comment: So i tried the above way i still didnt get any results. Can you please tell me if my query is wrong?

Comment: If you get an empty list (or a completely different message), then this question is answered, please accept the answer and open a new question with the new problem (for example: "getting a new list what query should I use").

Comment: So, is the curl command correct? or should i open a new question for this?

Comment: The command is correct if it executes, makes a query to the server and you get a reply (without syntax errors). For me it says "service test1 not found", which is correct as I do not have such a service, but shows that the server performed what I asked - to filter on tasks. If I use something that I have (like for example {"desired-state":["running"]} ) I do get a list of tasks.

Comment: Hi @vignesh at the answer seems to have solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This is the habit on stackoverflow and indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.