# How do I map combination keys

Tags: curl, couchdb, libcurl

I am working on the Apache CouchDB using the cURL.
I have created a database added database files & created a view.
I have made the following configurations for mapping the keys to the view.

```
function (doc) {
   emit([doc.key1, doc.key2, doc.key3], doc);   
}
```

I would like to access the database file using a combination of keys.
i.e.
In the above case, key1 is fixed in my URL's get request.
but I don't have control over key2 & key3(sometimes I have key2 & rest I have key3).

Will you please help me to know,
How can I access the database with a combination of key1-key2 OR key1-key3?

Comment: Will a document ever have both key2 and key3? Is it important to differentiate the two keys in a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this Guide with compound keys: https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/ddocs/views/collation.html#examples

Thus, you could try something like this:

```
startkey=[<val_key1>]&endkey[<val_key1>,{}]
```

or

```
startkey=[<val_key1>,<val_key2>]&endkey[<val_key1>,<val_key2>,{}]
```

If you use cURL, don't forget to encode the curly brackets or use option -g/--globoff ([Passing a URL with brackets to curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333920/passing-a-url-with-brackets-to-curl)).

EDIT:

- There is no space between the keys (write `[<val_key1>,{}]` instead of `[<val_key1>, {}]`)
- Likely, you have to create multiple views for each of your available key combination (key1-key2, key2-key3, key1-key3) combination because e.g. `[{},<val_key2>,<val_key3>]` does not work and will return you no rows. If you want to group by `<val_key2>` or `<val_key3>` you have to emit them first. (see also https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-give-muliple-composite-keys-in-startkey-and-endkey-to-search-in-views/629)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the database with a combination of key1-key2 OR key1-key3?

If you want to access documents based on the existence or value of `key1`, `key2`, `key3`, you most likely don't want to create a View that simply emits *all* them as keys.

Instead, first have a look at [Mango queries](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html) using the `_find`-API and construct them s.t. the desired documents are returned. For example:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "key1": {
      "$gt": null
    },
    "key2" {
      "$lt": "too high"
    }
}
```

The, create a matching [index](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/find.html#db-index) or [view](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/ddocs/views/index.html) for your queries.