# Bash: warning: here-document at line delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')

Tags: bash, eof, heredoc

The following function in bash comes up with the error mentioned  in the title. The error usually appears when the final `EOF` is not at the beginning of the line.

`EOF` is at the beginning so I can't see what is wrong. Further up in the script (not shown) there are other here-docs and they work.

```
add_testuser()
{
    kadmin -p admin -q addprinc test
    cat <<EOF > ~/test.ldif
dn: cn=test,ou=groups,dc=${ARRAY[1]},dc=${ARRAY[2]}
cn: test
gidNumber: 20001
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixGroup

dn: uid=test,ou=people,dc=${ARRAY[1]},dc=${ARRAY[2]}
uid: test
uidNumber: 20001
gidNumber: 20001
cn: First_name
sn: Last_name
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/test
userPassword: {CRYPT}*
EOF 

    ldapadd -Qf ~/test.ldif
    kdestroy; kinit test
    klist
    ldapwhoami
}
```

Comment: If you like an answer, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer. It gives the responder reputation points and lets everyone else know you aren't looking for a better answer.

Comment: @tripleee It's an exact duplicate: this question explicitly points out that there is no indentation, where the dupe target's problem _was_ indentation (even though you have to read through comments to see that). OTOH, it might be considered canonical because the top answer addresses both concerns.

Comment: Hmmm, so you basically agree with the duplicate marking? Or are you suggesting I change something?

Answer (score 40):

You have a space after the final `EOF` hence it was unable to terminate the heredoc.

p/s: Noticed this while copy-pasting your code.

Comment: Certainly, this fixed a similar problem I had - an extra space after the here-document terminator string.

Comment: Not always a space in my case it was a tab.

Comment: Nice sleuthing; the bottom line is that _nothing_ may be placed after the closing here-document delimiter.

Comment: Indenting the "EOF" also seemed to invalidate it, in my case.