# redirecting here-document, delimited by end-of-file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to print some html text to an html document with a here-script with the following snippet. $file is sometext.html, and whenever I run this I get an error:

> `line 126: warning: here-document at line 107 delimited by end-of-file (wanted _EOF_)`

```
#!/bin/bash


echo << _EOF_ 
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>
        $TITLE $HOSTNAME
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>$TITLE</h1>
    <p>$pTIME_STAMP</p>
    $(system_info) <br>
    $(show_uptime) <br>
    $(drive_space) <br>
    $(home_space) <br>
    </body>
    </html>
_EOF_ 

exit 0
```

Edit: I'm mostly copying the answer from [How can I write a here doc to a file in Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953081/how-can-i-write-a-here-doc-to-a-file-in-bash-script?rq=1)

Comment: Did you mean to use `cat` instead of `echo`?

Comment: Yes, I originally was using cat then tried echo just because, I'll change that back.

Comment: Hmmm... this works great for me after switching to `cat`.  Is there something else going on in a surrounding script?  Is there something odd about the contents of the document (the "html stuff")?

Comment: What is on line 107 of the script?

Comment: Are you sure the `_EOF_` line is at the left margin, like you show?

Comment: Or if it's indented, it must be indented with TAB characters, not spaces.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a space **after** `_EOF_` on that line, either. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503581/bash-warning-here-document-at-line-delimited-by-end-of-file-wanted-eof

Comment: @Barmar A tab will work only if the delimiter has a dash `-` : `<<-_EOF_`

Comment: @BinaryZebra Which his script does have.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry, but I can not see it, I see (copied from the question): `echo << _EOF_`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra He's edited the question. It used to say `cat <<- _EOF_ > "$file"`

Comment: @mtveezy Why have you put back `echo << _EOF_`? `echo` doesn't use its standard input, so it makes no sense to redirect it.

Comment: You have a space after `_EOF_`, just like in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure there is no space before **and after** the last `_EOF_`