# Laravel - POST data is null when using external request

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I'm trying to implement a simple rest api.

I have the controller implemented, and tested via unit testing.

My problem is with the POST request.

Via the tests Input:json has data, via an external rest client it returns null.

This is the code on the unit test

```
    $newMenu = array(
      'name'=>'Christmas Menu', 
      'description'=>'Christmas Menu',
      'img_url'=>'http://www.example.com',
      'type_id'=>1,
    );
    Request::setMethod('POST'); 
    Input::$json = $newMenu;
    $response = Controller::call('menu@index');
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

This is realy driving me crazy

I've instanciated a new laravel project and just have this code:

Routes

```
Route::get('test', 'home@index');
Route::post('test', 'home@index');
```

Controller:

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public $restful = true;
    public function get_index()
    {
        return Response::json(['test'=>'hello world']);
    }
    public function post_index()
    {
        return Response::json(['test'=>Input::all()]);
    }
}
```

CURL call:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -H"Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"world"}' http://localhost/laravel-post/public/test
```

response:

```
{"test":[]}
```

Can anyone point me to what is wrong.

This is really preventing me to use laravel, and I really liked the concept.

Comment: Have you tried it in a browser?  Just to make sure your curl call isn't the problem?

Comment: I tried it using a rest client (CocoaRest Client), But I haven't created the gui yet, so no browser test yet

Answer (score 8):

Because you are posting JSON as your HTTP body you don't get it with **Input::all()**;
You should use:

```
$postInput = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postInput, true);

$response = array('test' => $data);
return Response::json($response);
```

Also you can use

```
Route::any('test', 'home@index');
```

instead of

```
Route::get('test', 'home@index');
Route::post('test', 'home@index');
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove header *Content-type: application/json* if you are sending it as key value pairs and not a json

Answer (score 3):

If you use : `Route::post('test', 'XYZController@test');`
Send data format : `Content-type : application/json`
For example : `{"data":"foo bar"}`

And you can get the post (any others:get, put...etc) data with :

```
Input::get('data');
```

This is clearly written in here : http://laravel.com/docs/requests
. Correct `Content-type` is very important! 

 I am not sure your CURL call is correct. Maybe this can be helpful : [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

I am using `Input::get('data')` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem, my response of post was always null. To solve that I put the body key in guzzle object, like this

```
$client = new Client([
        'headers' => [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => config('app.callisto_token'),
        ]
    ]);

    $body = [
            'firstResult'=> 0,
            'data' => '05/05/2022'
        ];

        $response = $client->post('http://'.$this->ip.'/IntegracaoERP'.'/status_pedido',
            ['body' => json_encode($body)]
        );
```

Don't forget the json_encode in body key.
Hope this helps.