# Input::all() is not working - laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel, tried posting data using the following cURL command but when I try to read data, it wouldn't do it.

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"id":100}' api.xyz.com/test
```

There's a solution here* using file_get_contents but I'm sure there must be a better way:
[Laravel - POST data is null when using external request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672628/laravel-post-data-is-null-when-using-external-request)

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following curl command

```
curl -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"name":"John", "surname":"Doe"}' http://localhost/laravel/public/test
```

and returned a json_encode(Input::all()) in my HomeController@test and got the following output

```
{"name":"John","surname":"Doe"}
```

**HomeController.php**

```
public function test()
{
    return json_encode(Input::all());
}
```

**routes.php**

```
Route::post('/test', 'HomeController@test');
```