# PHP POST curl terminal command in PHP script

Tags: php, post, curl

I've found at the StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest) exactly how I want to post data to another web url.

However, I want this command to be executed in my php web script, not from the terminal. From looking at the curl documentation, I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
<?php 

$url = "http://myurl.com";
$myjson = "{\"column1\":\"1\",\"colum2\":\"2\",\"column3\":\"3\",\"column4\":\"4\",\"column5\":\"5\",\"column6\":\"6\"}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myjson);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

What is the best way to do that?

The current terminal command that is working is:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"column1":"1","colum2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5","column6":"6"}' https://myurl.com
```

Comment: Did you run this code? Short of improper strings, you're on the right track.

Comment: I did, just to be sure. It isn't accessing the url, while my terminal command is working (which I added to question).

Comment: Well, `$myjson ` is not set correct... change the first and last " for ' ;) (quote it correctly!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. You need to properly quote `$myjson`. Read the difference between [single and double quoted strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) in PHP.
2. You are not sending the curl request: [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php)

This should move you in the right direction:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://myurl.com';
$myjson = '{"column1":"1","colum2":"2","column3":"3","column4":"4","column5":"5","column6":"6"}';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myjson);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I can't believe I forgot that! :)