# How should I format a JSON POST request to my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rest

My Rails app has a player class that works perfectly. Players can be created, deleted, and updated from my rails control panel without any issues.

I would like a remote counterpart to be able to join in the fun by creating players using a JSON request. Following the advice of the auto generated Rails comments above my create method : `# POST /players.json` I have started sending requests to `localhost:3000/players.json`

**The JSON**

```
{
    "player": {
    "name": "test",
    "room_id": 0,
    "skin_id": 1,
    "head_id": 2,
    "torso_id": 3,
    "legs_id": 4,
    "x_position": 5,
    "y_position": 6,
    "direction": 7,
    "action": "",
    "gender": "f"
    }
}
```

However, I am running into this error message:

`ActionController::ParameterMissing in PlayersController#create
param not found: player`

So I guess my question is: **How should I structure the JSON I am sending?**

**Additional info:**

- Ruby Version: 2.0
- Rails Version: 4.0
- I have tried sending my requests using [Postman](http://getpostman.com/)

**Update - Player Params**

Here is the player params method from my controller (as requested):

```
def player_params
    params.require(:player).permit(:name, :room_id, :skin_id, :head_id, :torso_id, :legs_id, :x_position, :y_position, :direction, :action, :gender)
end
```

**Update 2 - Player controller**

```
class PlayersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_player, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }

  # GET /players
  # GET /players.json
  def index
    @players = Player.all
  end

  # GET /players/1
  # GET /players/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /players/new
  def new
    @player = Player.new
  end

  # GET /players/1/edit
  def edit
    @rooms = Room.all.map { |room| [room.name, room.id] }
  end

  # POST /players
  # POST /players.json
  def create
    @player = Player.new(player_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.save
        format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @player }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /players/1
  # PATCH/PUT /players/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @player.update(player_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @player, notice: 'Player was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @player.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /players/1
  # DELETE /players/1.json
  def destroy
    @player.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to players_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def manage_furni
    @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    @furni = Furni.all
  end

  def add_furni
    player = Player.find(params[:id])
    player.furnis << Furni.find(params[:furni])
    redirect_to manage_furni_path(player)
  end

  def remove_furni
    player = Player.find(params[:id])
    item = InventoryItem.find(params[:item])
    player.inventory_items.delete(item)
    redirect_to manage_furni_path(player)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_player
      @player = Player.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def player_params
      params.require(:player).permit(:name, :room_id, :skin_id, :head_id, :torso_id, :legs_id, :x_position, :y_position, :direction, :action, :gender)
    end
end
```

**Update 3: logs**

```
(
    "Processing by PlayersController#create as JSON",
    "Completed 400 Bad Request in 31ms",
    "ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: player):",
    "app/controllers/players_controller.rb:103:in `player_params'",
    "app/controllers/players_controller.rb:40:in `create'",
    "Rendered /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.5ms)",
    "Rendered /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.9ms)",
    "Rendered /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.8ms)",
    "Rendered /Users/drewwyatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (16.3ms)"
){
}
```

Comment: Did you write a method to require the player params in your controller? https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: I am using the rail auto-generated params. Check my update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you go ahead and show your entire controller code too? Thanks.

Comment: @jason328 just added it.

Comment: I solved a similar issue in a different way: instead of worrying about formatting a json POST, I just called a regular POST concatenating the usual POST string format and the server does not need to altered. If you are interested, I can reference how to do that.

Comment: Can you post the line from the log file when the POST request hits the server. I just want to make sure the parameters are being passed correctly from postman.

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam Just added it in update 3. Sorry it took me so long to get back to you - just saw your comment today. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and I'm beginning to think it's an issue with Postman. When I post as **form-data** using the format `player[name]=value` it works. When I post as **raw** with json in the format `{"player":{"name":"value"}}` it fails. Parameters never make it to the app. Has this happened to anyone else? @MarcoPoli  @anwyatt @moeso

Comment: @Smam it looks like to me that sending this as player[name] would be sending your data in an array, not JSON (I think).

Comment: @anwyatt that is totally possible. I don't really know the intricacies of POSTing. The only thing I do know is that when I run `params.inspect` in the controller the json never makes it in whereas the form-data does. Is there anything I need to do in the controller to permit json?

Comment: @anwyatt finally got it to work. I think it was a case of invalid json syntax and not setting my header properly as is shown in the answer below.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

First of all, I think your data format is ok and is not the problem here. When I ran exactly into the same problem it was because I did not send the `Content-Type: application/json` header along with my request.

In Postman, you can select the 'raw' data format and then 'JSON (application/json)' to include this header. In my case it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of sending a JSON request to a rails application in Postman]

Alternatively, you can also try it with `curl` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)):

`curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"player": {"name": "test","room_id": 0,"skin_id": 1,"head_id": 2,"torso_id": 3,"legs_id": 4,"x_position": 5,"y_position": 6,"direction": 7,"action": "","gender": "f"}}' localhost:3000/players.json`

If you omit the `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`, then you will receive a 400 response with the "param not found" error, if you include it it should work.

Comment: i am facing issue with rail serever when i send json via post man and all header set it works on postman but when same thing i send using my ios code it give me error 500 i am messed up from 5 days on this issue

Answer (score 6):

If you are trying this:

via Postman - Under form-data tab, you need to have the vars as :

```
player[name]
player[room_id]
.
.
```

via jQuery:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'url', type: 'post', data: { player: { name: 'Test', room_id: '0' } } })
```

Comment: Thanks, this was useful for getting PyCurl to send data in a Rails-compatible way and fix the 408 errors I was getting.

Comment: don't you also need a csrf token?