# How can I read the HTTP post request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

My question is familiar with:
[How should I format a JSON POST request to my rails app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690196/how-should-i-format-a-json-post-request-to-my-rails-app)

I am rookie in ruby on rails...just for 1 month study.
I create a Rails with some easy funtions like CRUD.
For now, i want to make some simple API for smartphone.

by use **POSTMAN** to test
GET is OK.
but **POST** always receive **Status 422 Unprocessable Entity**

what problems in my code... or does something i forget?
thanks a lot...

The following are my codes.

controller:

```
  def index
    @users = User.all
    render :json => @users
  end

  # GET /beacons/1
  # GET /beacons/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    render :json => @user
  end

  def create

    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save

    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @user }
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :name)
    end
```

routes:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, :defaults => { :format => :json } 
    end
  end
```

use rake routes:

> ```
>   api_v1_users GET    /api/v1/users(.:format)            api/v1/users#index {:format=>:json}
>                POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)            api/v1/users#create {:format=>:json}
> ```

my post:

> { "user": {"email": "2", "password": 2, "name": "2" } }

url:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue with CSRF token, in `application_controller.rb`, try replacing

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

with

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Also if possible post your question with the error log from `rails s`

Comment: oh!!! thank you very much!!! it seems like should pay more attention on how to set CSRF token.