# Creating a fulfillment via the Shopify API

Tags: api, curl, shopify

I am having trouble creating a fulfillment via the API. I am currently using curl to test, but am receiving a "Required parameter missing" error.

Anybody able to catch the error?

curl command:

`curl -i -v -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d "{'fulfillment': {'tracking_number':   null,'line_items': [{'id': 322959149}]}}" https://[apikey]:[password]@[shop-name].myshopify.com/admin/orders/186122043/fulfillments.json`

curl output:

```
* About to connect() to [shop-name].myshopify.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 204.93.213.94...
* connected
* Connected to [shop-name].myshopify.com (204.93.213.94) port 443 (#0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: serialNumber=inVwoUGzj3duFEUBdzDQrbS2kO1qx0Vr; C=CA; ST=Ontario; L=Ottawa; O=Jaded Pixel Technologies Inc.; CN=*.myshopify.com
*    start date: 2010-05-10 22:23:08 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-08-12 19:17:14 GMT
*    subjectAltName: [shop-name].myshopify.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Equifax; OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user '4a93b24da162b9ce3f6426206b63e692'
> POST /admin/orders/186122043/fulfillments.json HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic NGE5M2IyNGRhMTYyYjljZTNmNjQyNjIwNmI2M2U2OTI6ZDljMWYwMDNlZWZiMDE1MmQ1MzExMGNjMzk1N2MzMDI=
> User-Agent: curl/7.24.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin12.0) libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8y zlib/1.2.5
> Host: [shop-name].myshopify.com
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Length: 76
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 76 out of 76 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx
Server: nginx
< Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 21:10:02 GMT
Date: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 21:10:02 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Status: 400 Bad Request
Status: 400 Bad Request
< X-ShopId: 2235177
X-ShopId: 2235177
< X-Shopify-Asset-Version: 529b6843243276ab3e385c6b38a3bd7b17b4b92f
X-Shopify-Asset-Version: 529b6843243276ab3e385c6b38a3bd7b17b4b92f
< X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 2/500
X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit: 2/500
< HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 2/500
HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_API_CALL_LIMIT: 2/500
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: DENY
< X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
< Set-Cookie: _secure_session_id=989c50f70ca8fd46d381770aa5ad3e72; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: _secure_session_id=989c50f70ca8fd46d381770aa5ad3e72; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
< X-Request-Id: 3c394e98aebf3ae3ba4c3f75b8f069be
X-Request-Id: 3c394e98aebf3ae3ba4c3f75b8f069be

<
* Connection #0 to host [shop-name].myshopify.com left intact
{"errors":{"fulfillment":"Required parameter missing"}}
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ' should "

curl -i -v -H "Accept: application/json" -X POST -d '{"fulfillment": {"tracking_number": null,"line_items": [{"id": 322959149}]}}' https://[apikey]:[password]@[shop-name].myshopify.com/admin/orders/186122043/fulfillments.json

following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest) should help you.

Comment: While this may have been the JSON format 9 years ago when this was answered, the new format is much more complex and, since the URL above doesn't specify an API version, it likely would not work any longer as posted. New format explained at:
https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-01/resources/fulfillment#post-fulfillments