# Store JSON with a resource controller in Laravel

Tags: json, api, rest, laravel

I'm working on a restful API solution in Laravel. My problem is that I cannot make my store function accept JSON. 
In my store function I have the following code (based on this tutorial http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api-updated--net-29785):

```
public function store()
{
    $url = new Url;

    $url->url = Request::get('url');
    $url->description = Request::get('description');
    $url->save();


    return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,
        'message' => 'test',
        'urls' => $url->toArray()),
        200
    );
}
```

When I send my data like this:

```
 curl -d "url=test&description=testing" localhost/api/v1/url
```

it works as expected and the record is inserted into my database.

However, when I try to post some JSON like this

```
curl -d '{"url":"test","description":"test"}' localhost/api/v1/url
```

I can't even return the data by using Request::get('url'). I've read here on SO that Input::all() or Input::json()->all() would work, but I still can't return the data i'm posting.
Any ideas how I can access url and description when it is posted as JSON?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest#answer-7173011

Comment: Adding the Headers as mentioned in that thread did not help.
Am I still suppose to retrieve it with Request::get('url'), when I post it as JSON?

Comment: $json = Request::json(); then $url->url = $json->url; etc

Comment: The Request::json() returns an error:
The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "object" given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using curl correctly to post a json, try this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url":"test","description":"test"}' localhost/api/v1/url
```

If you are using a Windows client, you can use Postman (http://www.getpostman.com/), a Chrome plugin.

Configure it to:

1) POST

2) raw (and paste your json in the box)

3) Header: Content-Type Value: application/json

And to do your tests you can use a simple router like this:

```
Route::any('test', function() {

    Log::info(Input::all());

});
```

And execute

```
php artisan tail
```

To see what happens when you post.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sadly it didn't make any difference. Further I tried to escape the double quotes (I'm on a Windows machine)
I left out in my curl that I'm authorizing using --user username:password but I don't assume it makes any difference? The authentication is successful.

Comment: The router will be called, but infortunatelly the Json data may not being passed correctly. Just edited to add some info for testing on Windows.