# How to use argv with cURL

Tags: php, curl, argv

I want to pass parameters with cURL and get it using [argv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

Just like -

```
curl 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx/test.php {MY JSON DATA}'
```

and I want this json data as an argument - like it should print an array of arguments like

```
Array
(
    [0] => test.php
    [1] => 2345232wqwfdwfsdf
)
```

---

*Note - I can use POST/PUT method for getting the data but I want to know can I use argv when using curl command?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the posting  of the data, see [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

As for reading it inside of php, it will be in $_POST

Comment: Yes I can use POST PUT method for this but I am just curious about use of argv with curl command :)

Comment: Since curl is fetching a url, its going through a http server of some sort, which means your data will be passed either GET or POST data, not as argv data to the php executable or the php script.

Comment: php (when run directly) does have support for argv, but its prefaced with the script being run. Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php