# How do you force a JSON response on every response in Laravel?

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel

I'm trying to build a REST api using Laravel Framework, I want a way to force the API to always responed with JSON not by doing this manulaly like:

```
return Response::json($data);
```

In other words I want every response to be JSON. Is there a good way to do that?

> **Update:** The response must be JSON even on exceptions like not found
>   exception.

Comment: So what you want is to be able to write `return $data` and have it translate into `return Response::json($data);`?

Comment: Use middleware for that. Create terminable one and simply have it return what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75492554/14344959

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To return `JSON` in the controller just `return $data;`

For a `JSON` response on errors, go to `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file and look at the `render` method.

You should be able to re-write it to look something like this:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // turn $e into an array.
    // this is sending status code of 500
    // get headers from $request.
    return response()->json($e, 500);
}
```

However you will have to decide what to do with `$e`, because it needs to be an `array`.  You can also set the status code and header array.

But then on any error, it will return a `JSON` response.

*Edit:  It's also good to note that you can change the `report` method to handle how laravel logs the error as well.  More info [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler).*

Comment: This will return the row xdeubg message and I need to have the laravel debug response

Comment: @MustafaDwekat, I'm guessing it ended up working?  Did you need to change anything from my answer?  If so, let me know and I'll update it.

Comment: After playing there for a while I actually can get whatever I want from it. Thanks a lot. that was helpful.

Comment: Puncher That was great I miss undersod it but I wanna add that you need to form your error response before you return like `$response = ['error_code'=> $e->getStatusCode() , 'trace'=>$e->getTrace()]` then return that.

Comment: @MustafaDwekat, ah, yes.  You have to turn your `Exception` into an array before passing it.  Glad it worked out.  Check out the [docs on the exception handler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#the-exception-handler) for more info on what you can do with the exception handler.  If you need these errors logged a certain way, you can control that as well by modifying the `report` method.  Cheers!

Comment: I found this answer useful for using this in conjunction with filtering by route (which I needed to force API responses to be JSON): https://stackoverflow.com/a/30052319/2053165

Answer (score 48):

Create a middleware as suggested by [Alexander Lichter](https://twitter.com/TheAlexLichter/status/969879256271597568) that sets the `Accept` header on every request:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Add it to `$routeMiddleware` in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file:

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    (...)
    'json.response' => \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
];
```

You can now wrap all routes that should return JSON:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['json.response']], function () { ... });
```

#### Edit: For Laravel 6.9+

Give the `json.response` middleware priority over other middlewares - to handle cases where the request is terminated by other middlewares (such as the `Authorize` middleware) before you get to set the `Accept` header.

To do this - override the constructor of you `App\Http\Kernel` class (`app/Http/Kernel.php`) with:

```
    public function __construct( Application $app, Router $router ) {
        parent::__construct( $app, $router );
        $this->prependToMiddlewarePriority(\App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class);
    }
```

Comment: This method is cleanest!
We can also add `Accept: application/json` in client-side but it's more consistent this way

Comment: You'll also need to give this middleware priority in case that other middleware terminated the request before that middleware took action.
To do this you should add `$this->prependToMiddlewarePriority(\App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class);` to the constructor of you `Http\Kernel` class

Comment: Edited the answer with the priority thing - 
This should definitely be the correct answer

Comment: I had better luck in Laravel 8+ prepending the rule to a group.  In my case the API middleware group.  `public function __construct( Application $app, Router $router ) {
    parent::__construct( $app, $router );
    $this->prependMiddlewareToGroup('api',\App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class);
}`

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to add this middle ware to the `api` group? As far as I understand (but I might be wrong) you can priotize the middleware by placing it as the first item? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#middleware-groups

Comment: Also a hint: Create this new class easily via `php artisan make:middleware ForceJsonResponse` and replace the content.

Answer (score 16):

## Laravel Middleware is Extremely useful in this use case.

### 1. Make `JsonResponseMiddleware` middleware.

> `php artisan make:middleware JsonResponseMiddleware`

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\ResponseFactory;

class JsonResponseMiddleware
{
    /**
     * @var ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    /**
     * JsonResponseMiddleware constructor.
     */
    public function __construct(ResponseFactory $responseFactory)
    {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // First, set the header so any other middleware knows we're
        // dealing with a should-be JSON response.
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        // Get the response
        $response = $next($request);

        // If the response is not strictly a JsonResponse, we make it
        if (!$response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response = $this->responseFactory->json(
                $response->content(),
                $response->status(),
                $response->headers->all()
            );
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

### 2. Register middleware in `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [

        'api' => [
            ...
            ....
            /// Force to Json response (Our created Middleware)
            \App\Http\Middleware\JsonResponseMiddleware::class,
        ],


        'web' => [
            ...
            ....
            /// Add Here as well if we want to force response in web routes too.
        ],
]
```

Now we will receive every response in `JSON` only.

**Please note that: Even exceptions will respond in JSON format**

Comment: Using middleware is better approach than returning response from constructor. Thanks dear. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75492554/14344959

Comment: I think some methods have been renamed in the `JsonResponse` instance. for example `$response->content()` is now `$response->getContent()` and `$response->status()` is now `$response->getStatusCode()`

Comment: Thanks @abe for your attention to the detail.

Answer (score 13):

I know this has been answered but these are not good solutions because they change the status code in unpredictable ways. the best solution is to either add the appropriate headers so that Laravel returns JSON (I think its `Accept: application/json`), or follow this great tutorial to just always tell Laravel to return JSON: https://hackernoon.com/always-return-json-with-laravel-api-870c46c5efb2

You could probably also do this through middleware as well if you wanted to be more selective or accommodate a more complex solution.

Comment: I think this is the best solution for the problem.

Comment: @engma its unaffected. FormRequest has to do with request validation/authorization.  The question/answer has to do with the response.

Answer (score 9):

I've used several mixed solutions also mentioned here to solve everything a bit more dynamic. The reason was here to always reply on every request below "/api" with a json response.

1. Create a Middleware to force JSON Output in `app/Http/Middleware/ForceJsonResponse.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        // set Accept request header to application/json
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. Add this new middleware on *TOP* of the api array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        ...

        'api' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        ...
    ];
```

3. Overwrite the render method of the Exception handler that all exceptions also response with JSON `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

```
  namespace App\Exceptions;

  use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
+ use Throwable;

  class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
  {

     ...


+    /**
+     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
+     *
+     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
+     * @param  \Throwable $e
+     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
+     */
+    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
+    {
+        // Force to application/json rendering on API calls
+        if ($request->is('api*')) {
+            // set Accept request header to application/json
+            $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
+        }
+
+        // Default to the parent class' implementation of handler
+        return parent::render($request, $e);
+    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, you should not modify request header because it may not reflect what the user truly want

With that said, however, i found a better solution: override the `shouldReturnJson()` method in the `ExceptionHandler`

`return $request->expectsJson() || in_array('api',$request->route()->getAction('middleware'));`

Answer (score 2):

You should not modify request header because it may not reflect what the user truly want, in general, this is not a very good practice

There is a much cleaner way to do this: override the `shouldReturnJson()` method in the `ExceptionHandler`

by default, it is `return $request->expectsJson()`, but you can override it to ("expect json" OR "from api route")

```
protected function shouldReturnJson($request, Throwable $e)
{
    return $request->expectsJson() || in_array('api',$request->route()->getAction('middleware'));
}
```

the "from api route" part can be achieved multiple way, you can either check if it is in the "api" middleware group, like i did :`in_array('api',$request->route()->getAction('middleware'))` or check if the current URI start with 'api/':`Str::startsWith($request->path(), 'api/')`

This work even with the `Authenticate` middleware as well, because the AUthenticate middle actually throw a `Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` for the `Handler` to handle

So with this change, all errors will return as json from api routes, including unauthenticated ones, without setting `Accept: application/json` header

Comment: This should be the accepted answered, I surprised other answer has this much up vote, changing header is not good at all.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is extending the Request class. Create `app/Http/Request.php` with the following

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Http\Request as BaseRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Request extends BaseRequest
{
    public function wantsJson(): bool
    {
        return Str::startsWith($this->path(), 'api/') || parent::wantsJson();
    }
}
```

and then in `public/index.php` add:

```php
use App\Http\Request;
```

Comment: Finally something that actually works!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **[After Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#defining-middleware)** and change structure of all responses

Middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ChangeResponseStructureMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $newContent = [
            'data' => $response->getOriginalContent(),
            'context' => [
                'code' => $response->getStatusCode()
            ]
        ];

        return $response->setContent($newContent);
    }
}
```

this middleware will force the response content to be like

```
{
   "data": "response content of controller",
   "context": {
       "code": 200 // status code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried this on Laravel 10 and I think this is much cleaner without modifying/creating new or framework files:

Setting the request header within the callback function

```
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
  app('request')->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
  Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() {
    Route::apiResource( 'csr', V1\CsrController::class);
  });
});
```

Comment: this will work but all return that use the request will also return json including errors