# Laravel 8 ajax request validation how to force json response?

Tags: php, json, validation, redirect, laravel-8

I have a validation in my Laravel 8 API which validates input from camera. Camera can not send any header which will say that it accept application/json. So Laravel send me 302 redirect response on error insted of errors in json. Is there a way how to force Laravel to send json response insted of redirect on validation error? Thanks for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you force a JSON response on every response in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36366727/how-do-you-force-a-json-response-on-every-response-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply a middleware in the route in order to set the header you need.

In order to achieve this task you need to create a middleware with this command: `php artisan make:middleware SetJsonContentType`.

Note: Replace `SetJsonContentType` with whatever name you likes.

The file will be generated under the `app/Http/Middleware` directory.

In the handle method of the Middleware you need to insert the following code:

```php
   $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
   return $next($request);
```

after this, you need to use the middleware in the request.
To do so, you need to add the middleware `SetJsonContentType` to the web section of the app/Http/Kernel.php file.
You will end with something like this:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\SetJsonHeader::class,
       //other middleware
    ],

    'web' => [
        // ...
    ],
];
```

I hope that this would help you.

Comment: Kindly, do not write duplicate answers as this duplicate question has been already answered.