# Laravel 8: 302 Redirection when POST/PUT methods called

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I've newly installed Laravel 8, and setup my api resources.

But when I try to create/update a record, it's redirect me with `302`to the home page...

- Here is my `api.php`:

```php
    Route::apiResource('addresses', AddressController::class);
```

- In my `AddressController.php`, my *store* method:

```php
    public function store(CreateAddressRequest $request)
    {
        return response()->json(Address::create($request->validated()));
    }
```

Need help (to understand), please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please set the header in postman - Accept: application/json.

Comment: Thank you ! I forgot to specify the header (accept: application/json)

Answer (score 0):

When you create through `store()` method, you have `CreateAddressRequest` class which validates your input. When the validation fails it redirects to the previous page and it could redirects to the homepage if there is no previous page.

For API, this behavior is not desirable since you want to return error message (in JSON) instead of redirection.

Example of using validator to return the error. [REST API in Laravel when validating the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162617/rest-api-in-laravel-when-validating-the-request)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was the header (accept: application/json) that i forgot to set, like you said.