# ControllerAdvice is not called without @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If i use `@RequestBody`, everything works fine. However, i cannot use `@RequestBody` when sending files.

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> postProduct(@Valid PostProduct postProduct, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            for (ObjectError objectError : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
                System.out.println(objectError.toString());
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }
```

The error is still thrown but the `handleMethodArgumentNotValid` of `ControllerAdvice` is not invoked.

I don't understand this behavior.

**UPDATE 1**

Here's the `PostProduct` class

```
@Data
public class PostProduct {
    @NotBlank(message = "product name must not be blank")
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    @UniqueElements
    private List<@NotNull @Positive Integer> materials;
    @NotEmpty
    @UniqueElements
    private List<@NotNull @Positive Integer> colors;
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Integer price;
    @NotNull
    private List<@NotNull @ProductImageConstraint MultipartFile> images;
}
```

The `ControllerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodArgumentNotValid(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        System.out.println("handleMethodArgumentNotValid");
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        List<ObjectError> objectErrors = ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors();
        return returnError(objectErrors);
    }
public static ResponseEntity<Object> returnError(List<ObjectError> objectErrors) {
        Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
        objectErrors.forEach((error) -> {
            String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
            String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
            errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
        });
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(errors);
    }
}
```

I use 1 custom validator, don't know it has anything to do with this strange behavior but i'll post it anyway.

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = ProductImageValidator.class)
@Target( { FIELD, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ProductImageConstraint {
    String message() default "not image or file empty";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

```
public class ProductImageValidator implements
        ConstraintValidator<ProductImageConstraint, MultipartFile> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(ProductImageConstraint constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(MultipartFile image, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        boolean isValid = false;
        String contentType = image.getContentType();
        if (contentType != null && contentType.contains("image") && !image.isEmpty()) {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reveal your `PostProduct`? And how do you call your API w/o body?

Comment: Can u share the ConrollerAdvice method and where is the use of RequestBody, you talking about ?

Comment: @NakulGoyal I just updated the required parts. Please have a look

Comment: @pirho with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`, i dont think i can use `RequestBody`

Comment: @NakulGoyal if i write the code like this `@RequestBody @Valid PostProduct postProduct`, the controllerAdvice method will be invoked, but i need the request to send image as well, so Json is not an option. Hence, `@RequestBody` is deleted

Comment: Have u tried using @RestControllerAdvise and @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class) ?

Comment: @NakulGoyal Sorry, still nothing.

Comment: @LaHai Have you tried this `https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334407/5001937`

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I found out the reason by looking at it in a different way. Please have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Found the Solution here [BindException thrown instead of MethodArgumentNotValidException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211076/bindexception-thrown-instead-of-methodargumentnotvalidexception-in-rest-applicat)

Basically, when your content type is not `application/json`, BindException will be thrown, otherwise MethodArgumentNotValidException will be.

Comment: From the stacktrace you should know which exception is actually thrown.

Comment: @NakulGoyal that's the problem, if you don't override BindException method, it will not show stacktrace or anything, only when i comment out ControllerAdvice, then it printed the stacktrace. So, please no downvote.