# Combine keyword / value pairs from JSON files into a single JSON for submitting with curl

Tags: json, linux, bash, curl

I want to add an array to the "fields"
How can I do that?

how to add a "**fields**" array?

```
fields=()
for f in NameData/*.json
do
        Name= cat $f | jq -r '.[] | .Name'
        Value= cat $f | jq -r '.[] | .Value'
        
        fields+= #how? 
        '{
            "name" : "'$Name'",
            "value": "'$Value'"
        },'
done
```

#output for fields

```
{
    "name" : "Test"
    "value" : "1"
},
{
    "name" : "Test2"
    "value" : "2"
},
...
```

Because next to post

```
function Hi(){
    curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \
        '{
                    #how to array in fields //while?
            "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "Test",
                        "value":"'1'",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Test2",
                        "value":"'2'",
                    }
                    ...
                ]
        ...
}}
```

How do I need to give more details?
Can you help me? Thanks.

My files here (JSON) like
I'm trying to get the name and value

```
xample.json
[
    ...
    {
        "folder" : "nobody",
        "name": "1TS",
        "value": "2",
        ...
    }
]
example2.json
[
    {
        "name": "TST",
        "value": "4.75",
        ...
    }
]
```

Comment: What are the `NameData/*.json` files like? I'm assuming something like `[{"Name":"Joe Smith", "Value":"$12.75", "OtherField":"OtherData"}]`, but will there always be exactly one array entry per file? Will it always contain both `Name` and `Value`? Or does the script need to deal with extra and/or missing entries?

Comment: yeah, I wrote the content of my files (son)

Answer (score 1):

Bash arrays are just collections of strings. Probably just collect the key/value pairs and then finish up by formatting it as JSON.

```sh
fields=()
for f in NameData/*.json
do
        fields+=$(jq -r '.[] | {name: .name, value: .value}' "$f") 
done
```

Notice also how you need a [command substitution to run a command and assign its output to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash) and how we avoid the [useless `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and spend just one `jq` call to extract both fields.

But probably a much better solution is just to use `jq` directly.

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$(
    jq -s '{ fields: map({name: .[0].name, value: .[0].value})}' NameData/*.json)"
```

Comment: Credit to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/433687/19240 for the basic inspiration and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do almost all of the work in `jq`, like this:

```
fields=$(jq -n '[inputs | .[] | {name, value}]' NameData/example*.json)
```

Explanation: `-n` makes it start with a null input, then `[ ]` creates a new array from each of the `inputs` (the files specified after, i.e. the `NameData/example*.json` files), stripping the top-layer array and selecting out just the `name` and `value` fields.

Note that the field names are case-sensitive; in some places you used `Name` and `Value`, in other places `name` and `value`. Make sure you use the correct capitalization for the data. If you need to convert it e.g. from capital to lowercase, you can do this:

```
fields=$(jq -n '[inputs | .[] | {name : .Name, value : .Value}]' NameData/example*.json)
```

To use this with `curl`, you need to get the quoting right (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614423/trouble-with-bash-shell-script-attempting-to-post-variable-json-data-using-curl)). It's probably easiest to single-quote most of the POST data, but switch to double-quoting for the `$fields` part:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d \
    '{
        "fields": '"$fields"',
    ...
     }'
```

Alternately, you could just create the whole thing in `jq`:

```
post_data=$(jq -n '{fields : [inputs | .[] | {name : .Name, value : .Value}], ... }' NameData/example*.json)
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$post_data" ...
```