# How to make a HTTPS request using curl and pass json

Tags: c, json, curl, https, cppunit

i am trying to make HTPPS request to a server to send json file using curl .
please help me out

Comment: What did you try so far? What is a specific problem you facing?

Comment: A note for newbies, before you post questions read   http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question means "I want to send JSON data to a server with cURL".

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/api/login
```

The above example taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173011/4108929) answer should work. Modify the text after `-d` accordingly.

Comment: using c program , i was trying to send the Json .problem was with expected header from the server