# Curl, Node, JavaScript: Unexpected error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, curl

I'm sending some JSON to a Node server via CURL:

```
curl.exe "-i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"command":"print \"foo\"","language":"python","procID":"8540"}' http://127.0.0.1:1337/myServer.js?execute=yes
```

I receive the data just fine, and can print it with console.log(...) which would indicate that it's a string. When I run a JSON.parse(...) on it, I get an error:

```
undefined:1
'{command:print "foo",language:python,port:8080}'
^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

Any ideas why this happens?

I should note that the JSON sent in the command line:

{"command":"print \"foo\"","language":"python","procID":"8540"}

passes JSONlint.

Comment: `'{command:print "foo",language:python,port:8080}'` is not valid JSON, even if it weren't wrapped in `'`

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest when sending with CURL, it was right.

Comment: CURL doesn't matter, the parsing is happening in Node.

Comment: So how would I make it valid?

Answer (score -1):

This is a JSON object, not a string that's being received.

Comment: You are asking a question and answer your self .. are you serious ?

Comment: Well, I did some investigation and then figured I'd answer the question I asked. The site lets you do that, did I do something wrong?