# Converting json string in a shell variable to string literal

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a shell variable which contains json as follows

{
    "test" :"test",
     "temp":"temp"
  }

This is a part of json that I got when parsed from jq, which is a json parser tool.But when I pass this to curl as a part of post request body, it is getting converted to

```
   '{' 
     '"test"' ':' 'test,'
      '"temp"' ':' 'temp'
   '}'
```

But I want it as

```
   '{
      "test" : "test",
      "temp" : "temp"
    }'

VAL=$(echo "$RET" | jq ".pending[$j].value")
```

VAL is the variable that will contain the json
  I need to pass this VAL as request body to curl

```
curl -X POST -H "$CONTENT_HEADER" -H "$AUTH_HEADER" http://localhost:8080/testApi -d $VAL
```

Comment: Care to post your bash code?

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Comment: Sorry for the editing i was using mobile, thanks

Comment: By the way, you should be using `--arg` instead of interpolating shell variables in your jq script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell is interpreting it as several arguments. Either quote the expansion (as in `-d "$VAL"`) or pipe it instead of saving it to a variable `jq '...' | curl ...`