# How to read json file passed through curl command

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest, curl

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data "@data.json"  http://localhost:3000/
```

Comment: Are you asking how to POST a file, or how to parse the result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7173011/14955

Comment: POST a file using curl to rest webservice

Comment: In that link they are passing data as parameter .I want to pass a json file itself...like data.json... not the json content

Comment: How about this one then: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7173621/14955  (but seems to be similar to what you are using now)

Comment: [How do you extract POST data in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295782/how-do-you-extract-post-data-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl can be used to send multiple types of content but the default of all being the application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If you need to send a file through the same , you need to put that in the header, and for putting a file you need to specify -d param for the same.

a sample use of the same can be as :

```
 $ curl -vX POST http://<servername>/<api>/v1/<jsonfilename.json> -d @<file.json> \
--header "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Comment: ok. If we passed like this there should be a POST method to handle this call. what will be the signature of that?