# Powershell & Curl - Using variables inside single-quoted JSON body

Tags: json, powershell, curl

I am currently trying to automate new user creation in our Zendesk ticketing system using Powershell and Curl.  The problem I am running into is that the curl json body is enclosed by single quotes and I need to reference a variable inside that body.  Here is what I have:

```
$Firstname = "Test"
$Lastname = "User"
$email= 'user@test.org'   
curl.exe https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{\"user\": {\"name\": \"$Firstname $Lastname\", \"email\": \"$email\"}}' -v -u myuser:mypass
```

This works fine if I type in regular text values inside the json, but how can I get it to recognize the variables $Firstname, $Lastname and $email?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$Firstname = "Test"
$Lastname = "User"
$email= 'user@test.org'   
$json=@"
{\"user\": {\"name\": \"$Firstname $Lastname\", \"email\": \"$email\"}}
"@
curl.exe https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json -d $json -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST -v -u myuser:mypass
```

Using a double-quoted *here-string* `@"<newline>...<newline>"@` makes specifying embedded `"` instances easy (no escaping for the sake of PowerShell's *own* syntax required), while still expanding variable references - see the [docs online](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or `Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`.

You're clearly aware of the **- unfortunate - additional need to `\`-escape the `"` instances**, but just to explain why that is needed:

When **passing arguments to an *external program***, PowerShell, after its own parsing and interpolation, *conditionally* wraps the resulting arguments in *double quotes* when concatenating them to form the argument list (a single string) to pass to the external utility. Unfortunately, this can result in *embedded* `"` instances getting discarded, and the only way to preserve them reliably is to `\`-escape them - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) for more information.

If you wanted to do it inline with a regular double-quoted string, you'd have to escape the `"` instances for PowerShell *too* (as `` `" ``), resulting in the awkward combination `` \`" ``:

```
"{\`"user\`": {\`"name\`": \`"$Firstname $Lastname\`", \`"email\`": \`"$email\`"}}"
```

---

*Afterthought*:

Ryan himself points out in a comment that **using a *hashtable*** to construct the data and then converting it to JSON with **`ConvertTo-Json`** and feeding it to `curl` **via stdin** is an alternative that **avoids the quoting headaches**:

```
# Create data as PS hashtable literal.
$data = @{ user = @{ name = "$Firstname $Lastname"; email = "$adUsername@mydomain.org" } }

# Convert to JSON with ConvertTo-Json and pipe to `curl` via *stdin* (-d '@-')
$data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | curl.exe mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json -d '@-' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -v -u myuser:mypass
```

Comment: I have the inline version `$body_j="{\`"user\`":\`"ti\`",\`"pass\`":\`"passw\`"}"`, then `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:5000/login -Method Post -Body $body_j -ContentType 'application/json'` and get `Invoke-WebRequest : SyntaxError: Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @Timo, I don't see any `\ ` in your command, so I don't have an explanation, but note that this question is about `curl.exe`, not `Invoke-WebRequest` and that comments aren't the right place for troubleshooting, so I encourage you to ask a _new question_.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use here-string as json body for Invoke-RestMethod as below

```
$bufferTime = 5
$requestBody = @"
{
"size": 0,
    "aggs": {
    "last_x_min": {
        "filter": {
        "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
            "gte": "now-$($bufferTime)m",
            "lte": "now"
            }
        }
        },
        "aggs": {
        "value_agg": {
            "avg": {
            "field": "time-taken"
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
"@

$esResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -URI http://locahost:9200 -TimeoutSec 15 -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $requestBody
```

This is the script I use to query Elasticsearch. No need to escape double quotes.

Comment: This works without `\ `-escaping the embedded `"` instances, because you're calling a _cmdlet_ (a PowerShell-native command, `Invoke-RestMethod`)  rather than an _external utility_ (such as `curl` in the OP's case). While I wish that these two invocation scenarios didn't require different quoting, they unfortunately do.