# What does '@-' mean in PowerShell after pipeline?

Tags: json, powershell, curl

In [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36004654/9546850), the suggested answer is supplying magic "stdin" string `'@-'` to the command option.

```bsh
# Create data as PS hashtable literal.
$data = @{ user = @{ name = "$Firstname $Lastname"; email = "$adUsername@mydomain.org" } }

# Convert to JSON with ConvertTo-Json and pipe to `curl` via *stdin* (-d '@-')
$data | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | curl.exe mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/users.json -d '@-' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -v -u myuser:mypass
```

It works like a charm, but what does the magic "stdin" string actually mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl`'s `-d` parameter optionally allows you to supply data *via a file* (its *contents*) rather than by direct value.

So as to distinguish direct values (the default) from a value representing a *filename*, filenames must be prefixed with `@` (which is a common convention in the Unix world).

In the Unix world `-` is a frequently used convention to represent *stdin* (standard input) in contexts where filenames are expected (depending on context it may also represent *stdout* (standard output).

Thus, `@-` effectively instructs `curl` to read the `-d` argument from *stdin*, which in PowerShell is (always) provided via the pipeline (`|`).

In your PowerShell command `@-` must be *quoted* (`'@-'`), because an unquoted `@` at the start of an argument is a *metacharacter*, i.e., a character with special syntactic meaning (it serves several functions, including [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting)).
Alternatively, you could escape just the `@` itself: `` `@- `` (PowerShell's escape character is `` ` ``, the so-called backtick).

Comment: Thank you!  Your explanation is very clear and educative.  I wasn't aware that the `-d` argument can take a file.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Toshi; the `@` prefix for arguments representing filenames rather than direct values is a common convention in the Unix world.