# Pass JSON Object in Rest web method

Tags: java, web-services

```
@GET
@Path("/addemployee")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addEmployee(@QueryParam("id") String id, @QueryParam("name") String name,@QueryParam("address") String address,@QueryParam("phone") String phone ) {
    employeeVo.setId(Integer.parseInt(id));
    employeeVo.setName(name);
    employeeVo.setPhone(phone);
    employeeVo.setAddress(address);
    employeeDao.addNewEmployee(employeeVo);     
}
```

I have this above method which takes parameter from an html form and add this data to database table.
I want to do the same but using json Object, So how to pass a Json Object as a parameter? and what dependency should I add to my Pom.xml file. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use a `JAX-RS` implementation, that you `post` your data following the `JSON` representation of your `POJO` EmployeeVo in the body of your request, you can simply do that:

```
@POST
@Path("/addemployee")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addEmployee(EmployeeVo employeeVo) {
    employeeDao.addNewEmployee(employeeVo);     
}
```

Here is an example of the corresponding JSON object to post in the body of your request:

```
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "foo",
   "phone" : "911",
   "address" : "bar",
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm confused about how to send the json Object in the URL ?

Comment: Assuming that you have curl, have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Comment: what is import in this post is _curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:3000/api/login_

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what is curl ..
I just want to pass data in a simple way as Json object..
is there another way to do that ?

Comment: curl is simply a little application allowing to launch HTTP request from a terminal, which os do you use?

Comment: windows ... and building web service using eclipse

Comment: If you don't want to use curl, you can use JQuery http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp

Comment: currently I just want to do this using get method from the url as I'm doing in the above code.. but now i want to do this using json object instead of QueryParam ..

Comment: it is not your role to manipulate a JSON object when you use a JAX RS implementation, you are supposed to deal with POJO, it is the role of your JAX-RS implementation to convert your JSON data into a POJO. But If you really want  to use the get method, you can either implement your own Provider or simply send the String representation of the JSON object through a given parameter then parses it manually but it is not what you are supposed to do once again

Comment: BTW which JAX-RS impl do you use?

Comment: I guess jboss ? actually I'm new to web service and I'm not sure.. thanks for the explanation you helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just accept the JSON as String in the service and make a JSON object out of it.
You can make use of the dependency below for making the JSON object.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20090211</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, actually I need to do that as Json Oject