# How to pass a json object as a parameter in a REST request URL with Springboot

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I have looked at the various answers and they do not resolve my issue. I have a very specific client need where I cannot use the body of the request.

I have checked these posts:

- [Trying to use Spring Boot REST to Read JSON String from POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313687/trying-to-use-spring-boot-rest-to-read-json-string-from-post)
- [Parsing JSON in Spring MVC using Jackson JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019562/parsing-json-in-spring-mvc-using-jackson-json/6019761#6019761)
- [Pass JSON Object in Rest web method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36695555/pass-json-object-in-rest-web-method)

Note: I do encode the URI.

I get various errors but illegal HTML character is one. The requirement is quite simple:

Write a REST service which accepts the following request

`GET /blah/bar?object=object11&object=object2&...`

object is a POJO that will come in the following JSON format

```
{
    "foo": bar,  
    "alpha": {       
        "century": a,
    }
}
```

Obviously I will be reading in a list of object...

My code which is extremely simplified... as below.

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, path = "/test")
 public Greeting test(@RequestParam(value = "object", defaultValue = "World") FakePOJO aFilter) {
     return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), aFilter.toString());
 }
```

I have also tried to encapsulate it as a String and convert later which doesnt work either.

Any suggestions? This should really be extremely simple and the hello world spring rest tut should be a good dummy test framework.

---- EDIT ----

I have figured out that there is an underlying with how jackson is parsing the json. I have resolved it but will be a write up.. I will provide the exact details after Monday. Short version. To make it work for both single filter and multiple filters capture it as a string and use a json slurper

Comment: "I have also tried to encapsulate it as a String and convert later which doesnt work either" - why doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON parameter in spring MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577782/json-parameter-in-spring-mvc-controller)

Comment: The error when encoding: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol

Answer (score 2):

If you use `@RequestParam` annotation to a `Map<String, String>` or `MultiValueMap<String, String>` argument, the map will be populated with all request parameters you specified in the URL.

```
 @GetMapping("/blah/bar")
 public Greeting test(@RequestParam Map<String, String> searchParameters) {
     ...
 }
```

check the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-requestparam) for a more in depth explanation.