# How to call API in cron?

Tags: php, cron

I'm a newbie, I have a project which needs to send daily reminders to users. I see that you can do this using cron jobs. However, I need to call the API which has the daily reminder. This API is an external one. How do I do that?

**UPATE:**
I need to invoke the API and then get the response and send email to users daily.

Comment: The same way you would if it was a web page. If you show us how you do that we can confirm that for you

Comment: Why not send the email upon API call?

Answer (score 13):

Curl is your friend. In your case, you would have something like this:

```
0 8 * * * curl -X POST -d '{"message":"content"}' apidomain.com/endpoint/
```

In my example, I specify POST even though curl will default to a POST when you specify data (with the -d option).  I've included it in case your API expects a different HTTP method like GET or PUT.

The curl manpage will help: https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

And see this answer for some help with JSON and curl:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173011/1876622

Comment: @Mary, as a follow up to this, you may want to use crontab.guru to confirm your crontab syntax and a 3rd party monitor like wdt.io to ensure you get notified if your cron schedule fails.  *Full disclosure: I am involved in both of those projects*

Comment: thanks for your response! Sorry I didn't make my question clearly as I ought to. I need to invoke the API and then get the response and send email to users daily. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't retrieve and process the response triggered by a cron job. Cron jobs are like fire and forget.

Comment: Never forget about old friends.