# POST json using Command Line : json output is wrong

Tags: php, json, curl

I am using below syntax to post some json Data to my URL

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -X POST -d '{"username":"davidwalsh","password":"something"}' http://myProjectURL
```

i would like to get this json string in array in my php function

but currently when i try to print the post variable like

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($post);
die();

it gives me output 
<pre>Array
(
    ['] => Array
        (
            [{username:davidwalsh,password:something}] =>
        )

)
```

**expected Output :**

```
 Array(
        "username" => "davidwalsh",
        "password" => "something"
    )
```

I am referring [this](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post-file)

Though my question is marked as duplicate but i would like to inform you that i am not able to get the each parameter i have sent through json .
I am getting all the `array` `key` `values` as a single array key which is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got the Answer :

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d "{\"username\":\"davidwalsh\",\"password\":\"something\"}" http://myProjectURL
```

i had to put **Double Quotes**`(")` around each parameter and the values with 
some modification in php file like below.

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input") , true);
    print_r($data);
}
?>
```

And the **output** i received is :

```
<pre>Array
(
    [username] => davidwalsh
    [password] => something
)
```