# How send file content in a form field on CURL?

Tags: node.js, curl

I use postman to send POST requests. I use form fields and I have a field "data". 
In these field I paste the complete content of a xml-file. It work fine!

Now I want use CURL to send this POST request with dynamic XML-content. But I looking for a simple way to fill the XML content in the field "data" on CURL command.

I try:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "data=@/my/file/path" http://localhost:3001/import/myservice
```

If I check the request in my nodejs code there is no content in request params only the filename.

My node code is:

```
router.post('/import/myservice', function(req, res) {
   let data = req.body.data;
   ... }
```

Content of data is "@/my/file/path" but I need something like

```
data= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> ...'
```

Answer (score -1):

If you put your data in a file you should enter the line like below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data "@my.file.path" http://localhost:3001/import/myservice
```

Take a look right
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173621/7823445) it might help.

Comment: --data "data=@my.file.path" ==> data = '@my.file.path' (nodejs)


and --data "@my.file.path" not working for me, I need formdata.

Comment: @brett I rember, my solution was: discard the file read-way. Use  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and do the encoded XML direct in the -data option. Hope it help's.