# Spring Cloud Data Flow does not work how is expected for file sink and curl client

Tags: curl, spring-cloud-dataflow

In Mac, working with `Spring XD`

- `1.3.2.RELEASE`

The following works fine:

`stream create --name orderFilter --definition "http --port=9090 | filter --expression=#jsonPath(payload,'$.countryCode').equals('US') | file --name=manolito.txt --dir=/Users/manueljordan/Desktop --mode=APPEND" --deploy`

Through its own `shell` the following works:

```
http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2773\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"100\"}"
http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2774\",\"countryCode\":\"CA\",\"orderAmt\":\"125\"}"
http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2775\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"110\"}"
```

The data is filtered and the output is located in `/Users/manueljordan/Desktop` how is expected.

Until here all is ok.

Now migrating to `Spring Cloud Data Flow` working with

- `spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar`
- `spring-cloud-dataflow-shell-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar`

Through the GUI (`http://localhost:9393/dashboard/index.html#/streams/definitions`) I can create the same stream.

Again through the shell (from *spring-cloud-dataflow-shell*) the following works:

```
  http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2773\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"100\"}"
  http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2774\",\"countryCode\":\"CA\",\"orderAmt\":\"125\"}"
  http post --target http://localhost:9090 --data "{\"id\":\"2775\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"110\"}"
```

The same http post used for `Spring XD`

**Situation 01** even when the three `http post` from above work about the filter behaviour, the output file is **not** created in `/Users/manueljordan/Desktop`, it is created in `/private/var/folders/nf/ql69b5zd7w54jw6nb5zmvck80000gn/T/dataflow/output` instead

Observe the `dataflow` directory within `ql69b5zd7w54jw6nb5zmvck80000gn`

Why this behaviour? How fix this?, some special configuration missing?

**Situation 02** about *cURL*, according with the reference documentation, in the [10.1. Endpoints](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#arch-data-flow-server-endpoints) section, just practically below the `Figure 3. The Spring Cloud Data Flow Server` shows that `cURL` can be used too.

Through `iterm 2` if I use the following commands: (it according with [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest))

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"{\"id\":\"2773\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"100\"}"' http://localhost:9090
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"{\"id\":\"2774\",\"countryCode\":\"CA\",\"orderAmt\":\"125\"}"' http://localhost:9090
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '"{\"id\":\"2775\",\"countryCode\":\"US\",\"orderAmt\":\"110\"}"' http://localhost:9090
```

Nothing happens (I press enter to execute the command and just pass to the new line prompt, that's all). Why? what is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1587#issuecomment-313266803

We monitor both SO and GitHub issues so no need to cross-post.

-Thomas