# format of data for a http POST resquest when using the curl command

Tags: http, curl, post, get

If I issue a `curl` command to a `REST` api then I get the response below.

```
curl -i http://10.4.0.22:8088/api/clients/TEST_1/8194/1/1
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 51
Server: Jetty(9.1.z-SNAPSHOT)

{"status":"CONTENT","content":{"id":1,"value":"0"}}
```

My understanding that this is equivalent to a http `GET` request.

What I'm trying to do is update the `value` field and change the value to `1`.

I think this requires a `POST` request using the `-d` flag.

My question is how do I know what format the data should be in the curl command?

I tried

```
curl -d "{"status":"CONTENT","content":{"id":1,"value":"1"}}" http://10.4.0.22:8088/api/clients/EST_1/8194/1/1
```

but I get this response.

```
{"status":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"}
```

I think the way that I am specifying the json after te `-d` flag is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response `METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED` means the server doesn't allow **POST** method.

You can add a **`-v`** to get a verbose output of the response. Sometimes the server responds back in the message as to what **`HTTP Methods`** (or **`Verbs`**) it allows.

I tried your parameters on my application endpoint and it worked. see below

```
curl -d "{"status":"CONTENT","content":{"id":1,"value":"1"}}" http://sitename.azurewebsites.net/index.php -v
* Adding handle: conn: 0x2c257d0
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x2c257d0) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to sitename.azurewebsites.net port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 104.211.224.252...
* Connected to sitename.azurewebsites.net (104.211.224.252) port 80 (#0)
> POST /index.php HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Host: sitename.azurewebsites.net
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 39
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 39 out of 39 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
< Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 14:24:08 GMT
```

You can also try to specify the **`Content-Type`** header in your request and set it to corresponding **`Mime`** value.

For CURL, you can use the `-H` with the value set to `"Content-Type: application/json"`

Have you seen this thread: [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

Comment: Thanks very much for your helpful reply.