# Express - Adding a JSON payload with curl causing parsing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

**Code:**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (req, res)
{
    res.send("Ok")
})

app.listen(7000)
```

**Works:**

curl -X POST localhost:7000/

**Fails:**

*Cmd:* curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"day":"Friday"} localhost:7000/

*Error:* SyntaxError: Unexpected token d in JSON at position 1

Any ideas?

**Resolution:**

The problems seems to be due to the fact I was doing this on Windows. The following commands worked.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"""day""":"""Friday"""}localhost:7000/

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {\"day\":\"Friday\"} localhost:7000/

curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"day\":\"Friday\"}" localhost:7000/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to POST JSON data with Curl from Terminal/Commandline to Test Spring REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest)

Answer (score 1):

The cURL command gets confused with the quotes (see how it thinks the first character is "d"?). You need to wrap the JSON data in single quotes:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"day":"Friday"}' localhost:7000/
```

You can also escape the quotes:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"day\":\"Friday\"}" localhost:7000/
```

Comment: Thanks. On my Windows setup, the first suggestion doesn't work (I did try that) but  the second does. Although it does require the outside quotes.

Comment: Sorry, I’m confused. Could you fix it? Yeah, the second one requires wrapping in double quotes **and** escaping the inside double quotes.