# How do I validate a IIIF manifest?

Tags: validation, iiif

I am trying to display a manifest from another IIIF server in my local viewer, but it doesn't seem to be working. How do I confirm the manifest is valid/not broken?

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate on your setup? IIIF seems pretty uncommon here, as it doesn't even have its own tag (yet). You might get more and better responses if you post some more info. The supposedly broken manifest maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a validator on the IIIF website that will validate IIIF Manifests, at http://iiif.io/api/presentation/validator/service/.

If you've got a lot of manifests to test, you can also download the validator itself at http://github.com/IIIF/metadata-api/.

Comment:  Thanks for this explanation (and to Andy Irving for creating the IIIF tag, woot!).

Jason R's answer below is also excellent if you need to validate manifests in your own environment, and is community-maintained.

Comment: If the manifest you're trying to validate is behind a firewall, you can also POST the contents of a generated manifests to the validator.  With curl, that would be something along these lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-to-post-json-data-with-curl-from-terminal-commandline-to-test-spring-rest

Answer (score 3):

There's also the Tripoli manifest validator: https://github.com/DDMAL/tripoli

And a live version of Tripoli: https://validate.musiclibs.net/

Comment: This one seems (at the moment) to have more options and documentation than the "official" validator hosted at the IIIF.io website. It's also been updated more recently, but has less contributors. In order to select an answer to this question, it would be nice to have some more details about why a developer might want to use one over the other.