# How to debug Flask API

Tags: python, debugging, flask, postman

I would like to debug my Flask API. The API requires a JSON payload from a user. I am supplying that payload through Postman.I am using PyCharms debugger and am able to debug for a few seconds before Postman times out and the connection is lost and I must start again. I have already set request timeout to infinity [image: Postman Response]
How can I maintain the connection in order to continue debugging?

Comment: You could use the command line utility curl.

Comment: Could you expand on how that works and how it would solve the problem?

Comment: Look at this post for how to send JSON using curl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl

Comment: Do you know of a solution using Postman

Comment: I don't, but judging from what's in the image maybe you should turn off SSL certificate verification since you're POSTing to a http:// address. Oh, and try adjusting the Request timeout.

Comment: I just tested and cURL has the same issue with timeout. I tried turning off SSL verification but no change

Answer (score 1):

The timeout time for a given Flask app can be edited in it's given config property. Setting 'timeout' to the number of seconds you need before the request time's out will solve the issue.