# Encode JSON in bash script

Tags: json, bash, zabbix

I'm trying to import a Template to my Zabbix server with Zabbix API, i used this:

```
fileJSON=\""$(cat template_file)"\"

curl  -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "configuration.import",
    "params": {
        "format": "json",
        "rules": {
            "templates": {
                "createMissing": true,
                "updateExisting": true
            }
        },
        "source": $fileJSON
    },
    "auth": "6a977cd94b26b6156698459ac4d0f769",
    "id": 1
}' 'http://127.0.0.1/zabbix/api_jsonrpc.php' | jq '.'
```

Here is the output:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error","data":"Invalid JSON. An error occurred on the server while parsing the JSON text."},"id":null}
```

I just don't see any error… i tried to use an online parser website but he Don't see any error. 
This var is directly filled with the export method of Zabbix (in JSON).
Here is the content of the file:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": "{\"zabbix_export\":{\"version\":\"4.4\",\"date\":\"2020-02-18T08:47:31Z\",\"groups\":[{\"name\":\"System\"}],\"templates\":[{\"template\":\"Template Systeme\",\"name\":\"Template Systeme\",\"groups\":[{\"name\":\"System\"}],\"discovery_rules\":[{\"name\":\"D\\u00e9couverte des services\",\"key\":\"service.discovery\",\"delay\":\"30s\"}]}]}}",
  "id": 1
}
```

I think that the error is the format of the fileJSON, how to encode this variable in JSON format ?

Comment: As a suggestion, why don't you create the JSON before you put it in Curl so you can check its validity?

Answer (score 2):

you're submitting your `JSON` using single quotes `'{...}'` which do not result in the interpolation of your `$fileJSON` - hence you receive that error.

Use double quotations instead:

```
curl  -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "{
...
```

you would need then quote the inner quotation marks of your `JSON` too.

There's also an easier way to interpolate `$fileJSON`, use it like this:

```
curl  -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "configuration.import",
    "params": {
        "format": "json",
        "rules": {
            "templates": {
                "createMissing": true,
                "updateExisting": true
            }
        },
        "source": '"$fileJSON"'
    },
    "auth": "6a977cd94b26b6156698459ac4d0f769",
    "id": 1
}' ...
```

that way will spare you a hassle quoting inner quotation marks

Comment: No, single quotes is the proper way to send JSON data with cURL. See this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)

Comment: shell interpolation occurs before argument is passed to the command and single quotes prevent it. `curl` simply would not know that `$fileJSON` requires an interpolation

Comment: Right. The single quotes around the argument to `-d` mean that the data being passed to `curl` contains the literal 9-character sequence `$fileJSON`; nowhere in there is the contents of the file you loaded into a shell variable _named_ `$fileJSON`.

Comment: Thank for your answer but that Don't solve the problem…

Comment: @BlueStraax what's the returned error in that case? I suspect that interpolation of `$fileJSON` does not go well. do you mind sharing the content of that variable?

Comment: @Dmitry when i type this: ``` '"$fileJSON"' ``` i have the same error as usual, the content of the variable is exactly the same as the content of the file with double quote at the start and at the end. You can see the content in my question.

Comment: @BlueStraax: ah, I missed that part. In this case the interpolation fails because your template_file contains double quotation marks (it's a `JSON`) and thus require _stringification_ before interpolation. Try setting `fileJSON` like this: `fileJSON="$(<template_file jq tostring)"` and then use my answer.

Comment: @Dmitry, still the same error… 
Here is an echo of the variable:
"{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"result\":\"{\\\"zabbix_export\\\":{\\\"version\\\":\\\"4.4\\\",\\\"date\\\":\\\"2020-02-18T08:47:31Z\\\",\\\"groups\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"System\\\"}],\\\"templates\\\":[{\\\"template\\\":\\\"Template_System\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Template_System\\\",\\\"groups\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"System\\\"}],\\\"discovery_rules\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"D\\\\u00e9couverte des services\\\",\\\"key\\\":\\\"service.discovery\\\",\\\"delay\\\":\\\"30s\\\"}]}]}}\",\"id\":1}"

Comment: @BlueStraax - that's the properly stringified JSON. I don't know the API requirement to supply your JSON, but if that fails, I may assume that API expect a constructed JSON rather than a stringified source. In such case try this way: `fileJSON="$(cat template_file)"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208054/discussion-between-bluestraax-and-dmitry).

Answer (score 1):

From the [API documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/api/reference/configuration/import):

> source (required) -   string  -  Serialized string containing the
>   configuration data.

You can find an XML source example:

```
"source": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><zabbix_export><version> [cut]
```

You are sending as `source` the full output of a `configuration.export` call:

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "result": "{\"zabbix_export\":{\"version\":\"4.4\",\"date\":\"2020-02-18T08:47:31Z\",\"groups\":[{\"name\":\"System\"}],\"templates\":[{\"template\":\"Template Systeme\",\"name\":\"Template Systeme\",\"groups\":[{\"name\":\"System\"}],\"discovery_rules\":[{\"name\":\"D\\u00e9couverte des services\",\"key\":\"service.discovery\",\"delay\":\"30s\"}]}]}}",
  "id": 1
}
```

while you have to send only the serialized string, which should be the value of the `"result"` field of your `fileJSON`:

```
"source": "{\"zabbix_export\":{\"  [cut]
```

Comment: Thank you for answer me, i think you right but that Don't solved the problem… Always the same error with or without the backslash… any idea ?

Comment: Try without the external file, use a static source inside your curl data. But a better idea is to avoid manual "curling": use an API implementation that takes care of escaping, authentication etc... I use pyzabbix, but it's a personal taste decision.

Comment: Always the same error i think i will use xml format or pyzabbix. thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the look of the `template_file` output, the `result` key is not JSON but JSON string. Have you tried without `JSON dump`ing it?

Comment: i didin't dump it, it's by default like that.
I Don't really know what's the difference between JSON and JSON string, that why my request was how to transform it in JSON format