# Github API error "Problems parsing JSON" when using curl but works fine with Postman

Tags: json, curl, github, github-api

I am trying to create a release using Github's API.

My request works fine in Postman but no matter what I've tried it always fails with curl, including if I just translate my Postman request into curl using Postman.

This is the body of my Postman POST request:

```
{
    "tag_name": "4.2.0",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "4.2.0",
    "body": "test"
}
```

I've included an authorization header of type "Basic", where I input my username and a token I have created for this purpose.

I am executing the request against `https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases`.

As I said - it works fine, but when I translate it into curl I get the error "Problems parsing JSON".

The translated curl command is:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <someHashOrSomething>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "tag_name": "4.2.0",
    "target_commitish": "master",
    "name": "4.2.0",
    "body": "test"
}'
```

which I reformat into `curl --location --request POST 'https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases' --header 'Authorization: Basic <someHashOrSomething>' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{   "tag_name": "4.2.0",    "target_commitish": "master",   "name": "4.2.0",    "body": "test"}'` to be on one line.

I also tried (since only the "tag_name" parameter is required):

`curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <myToken>' -d '{"tag_name":"4.2.0"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases`

`curl -i -H 'Authorization: token <myToken>' -d '{"tag_name":"4.2.0"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases --header Content-Type:application/json`

`curl -d '{"tag_name":"4.2.0"}' -u <myUsername>:<myToken> https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases --header "Content-Type:application/json"`

`curl -d "tag_name=4.2.0" -u <myUsername>:<myToken> https://api.github.com/repos/<myUsername>/<myRepo>/releases --header "Content-Type:application/json"`

Every curl request fails with the "Problems parsing JSON" error.

Comment: Im curious why you use `--data-raw` here rather than just `--data`, as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7173011/1363815

Comment: There may also be some issues with correctly escaping the quotes in the JSON, depending on which OS and shell you are using (see comments)

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing this from the windows cmd prompt, you need to change

```
--data-raw '{   "tag_name": "4.2.0",    "target_commitish": "master",   "name": "4.2.0",    "body": "test"}'
```

to

```
--data-raw "{   \"tag_name\": \"4.2.0\",    \"target_commitish\": \"master\",   \"name\": \"4.2.0\",    \"body\": \"test\"}"
```

cmd prompt appears to not like single quotes for the data.

Comment: Confirmed, use regular quotation for the json string and escape quotation within. Bummer because this prevents easy copy&paste.

Answer (score 1):

How to debug:

- Add "-v --trace-ascii -" to the curl command to see log for command.
- Use  echo or write-host for your data in cmd or PowerShell

Remember that It is so important to make sure that curl receives valid JSON data.

See an example of Powershell [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71158464/5925125):

Answer (score -5):

The problem could be your API key.

Check if it has the sufficient permissions or try and create a new one.

Comment: This is not an answer. Use the comment section for such message.

Comment: @SwatantraKumar it is so an answer, I had the same problem some time ago and that's how I fixed it.