# Unable to add questions on my project for trivia api

Tags: python, json, api, curl

Whenever I try adding questions it would give me the following error

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/questions -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "question": "Which US state contains an area known as the Upper Penninsula?", "answer": "Michigan", "difficulty": 3, "category": "3" }'
```

and I would get this result :

```
{
  "error": 400,
  "message": "bad request",
  "success": false
}
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: question
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Which US state contains an area known as the Upper Penninsula
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: answer
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Michigan,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: difficulty
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 3,
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: category
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 3
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1
```

this is the project i am trying to run https://github.com/suhanesh02/trivia_api I am currently trying to run backend  and I am running it on windows. So i did the following cd backend , then installed flask, on Postgres : created database trivia once I did that tried to run flask.

Comment: Please provide version of software you are using. Also what is the code for the endpoint the request is trying to reach?

Comment: Is this linux/mac or windows?

Comment: This is [curl globbing](https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline/cmdline-globbing) but I'm not sure why you are getting it.

Comment: curl'ing JSON POST data from Windows requires the [quotes be escaped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)