# Curl troubles sending long encrypted string by URL param

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to send a long encrypted string with curl to an api and it gives me this

````
curl http://host.net/crypto.php?api=XXXXXXXX\&name=XXXX\&msg=$key
bash: /usr/bin/curl: Argument list too long```
````

If i try to send a file

```
curl http://host.net/crypto.php?api=XXXXXXX\&name=XXXX\&msg="@/tmp/.sendenc"
```

The server just gets `@/tmp/.sendenc`

The first way works fine with shorter strings but not with longer...

idk if this helps but its sending an encrypted image about 417025 letters :/

Comment: It might be because your URI is too long - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184

Comment: @zmike Thank you! That actually makes alot of sense do you have suggestions on how i could send/transfer the data?

Comment: Break up the data somehow, or use POST requests instead of GET. See https://ec.haxx.se/http/http-post or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl for examples.

Comment: Use POST for any long set of datas