# Post request in Curl Windows for Api testing

Tags: api, rest, curl, postman

I'm new in Postman testing Api procedure and have a question how to send Api request in curl Windows. I was looking through stack and tried to do as described but it doesn't work for me.
So here is my request

- curl https://suggestions...../api/4_1/rs/suggest/fio ^
- –data-raw "{"query": "A","count": 3}" ^
- H "Content-Type: application/json" ^
- -H "Accept: application/json" ^
- -H "Authorization: Token 8997978" ^         -X POST

[here is the result from cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVL2K.png)

The question is how to send post request with json from Curl in Windows. Not from File.

Comment: Have a look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I POST JSON data with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

curl -X POST 
https://suggestions...../api/4_1/rs/suggest/fio
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Accept: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: Token 8997978" 
-d '{"query": "A","count": 3}'