# Formatting curl command

Tags: curl, post, https, git-bash

In Windows Git Bash, this curl command works:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=6BfkncD9ypGMiHkjrfka5ydqrG4GLx1z&client_secret=EC5i7QG61Qg8jDmZ&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read'
```

But when I try to format the contents in -d, it doesn't work:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'client_id=6BfkncD9ypGMiHkjrfka5ydqrG4GLx1z&
    client_secret=EC5i7QG61Qg8jDmZ&
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    scope=data:read
  '
```

Anyway I can format it and it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`-d`/`--data`/`--data-ascii`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) option of curl sends a data which is expected to be in one line in case of URL paraleters (as opposed to JSON, as [seen for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56325350/6309), where the data can be on multiple lines).

That means you need to build your string first in a variable, then use that variable in curl.

```sh
vonc@vclp MINGW64 /c/test
$ data=$(printf '%s' '
    client_id=6BfkncD9ypGMiHkjrfka5ydqrG4GLx1z&
    client_secret=EC5i7QG61Qg8jDmZ&
    grant_type=client_credentials&
    scope=data:read
' | sed ':a; N; $!ba; s/\n\s*//g')

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' \
  -X 'POST' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d "${data}"
```

So two steps in this case.