# how to use post method in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, post, node-modules, body-parser

I am using post method in nodejs

Well it is working fine when I run it using postman

but when I run it in my browsers it shows error

`Cannot GET /listUsers`
and
`listUsers:1 GET http://localhost:8081/listUsers 404 (Not Found)`
this

here is my node js code

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.post('/listUsers', function (req, res) {
        var f = parseInt(req.body.f);
    console.log("hello" + f);
   var l = parseInt(req.body.l);
    var sum = Number(f + l);
    res.send('The sum is: ' + Number(sum));
})
var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

here is my jquery code from where I am sending data

```
usid();
function usid(med){
  var f = "my new name";
  $.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url:"http://localhost:8081/listUsers",
    method:"POST",
    data:{med,f:f},
    success:function(data,status){
      console.log("send");
    }
  })
}
```

can I get where I am doing mistake?

Comment: You can only send GET requests with browsers.

Comment: For testing `post, delete, put or patch` use `cuRL` or `postman`.

Comment: Here is an [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)

Comment: but in get method I cannot send data and I am using webrtc and I am connecting the nodejs with php through ajax so I have to send and receive data from my nodejs so if I cannot use post then can you suggest me any other http method to pass or receive data in browsers??@murat colyaran,@sefa

Comment: What data are you sending in you listUsers? Do not see any in your code. Check how query parameters work to send some data with GET.

Comment: Actully I am sending the data from Jquery ajax to nodejs  but its not working @Tushar shahi

Comment: Please show your jQuery code too.

Comment: I have update my question and added the jquery code too in it @TusharShahi

Comment: what is your jQuery version ? before 1.9 there was not any "method" properties in $.ajax, instead it was "type"
you could also try use $.post

Comment: my jquery version is 2.2.4 @r043v

Comment: your error message is clear that it's a get request, you may missform your $.ajax
give a try at $.post : $.post("/listUsers",{hello:"world"},function(data){ console.log(data); });

Comment: in my own test all work fine, using $.ajax like you with your options and same url formatting or directly with $.post, what is this "med" variable used to construct your post values ?

Comment: I have tried this too but its not working ?@r043v

Comment: data:{med,f:f} this is not valid

Answer (score 1):

You are not submitting any form/storing any resource. What you are trying should ideally be done with GET.

Reasons it is not working with browser:
Visiting a page by changing url is a GET method. You do not have a GET method defined in your app for this route. Only one POST method.

What you can do:
Change POST to GET both in server and your AJAX. Change both methods accordingly. You will then have to pass [query params](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-access-query-string-parameters/)(google something and everything after the question mark is how query Params work).