# curl gives error while postman works as intended "Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes"

Tags: python, api, flask, curl, postman

When I give the following curl command (and various other formats below), I keep encountering error, however it posts just fine with Postman:

`curl --location "http://localhost:5000/user/signup" --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data-raw "{ "name":"Raj Kumar","email":"raj@example.com","password":"samplepassword" }"`

`curl --location "http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/signup" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{ "name": "Raj Kumar", "email": "raj@example.com", "password": "samplepassword" }'`

Errors I get:
`Failed to decode JSON object: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 3 (char 2)` 
`curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 53:` 
`Kumar,email:raj@example.com,password:samplepassword }`

`curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Postman:
[image]

I have tried formatting the code multiple times but it doesn't seem to work. I also tried swapping the double quotes with single ones too.

I was expecting the same output as Postman below:

Comment: I later found out gitbash works as intended. But I still want to know the answer to this.

Comment: Single quotes might not work everywhere, https://stackoverflow.com/a/24499743/1427878 - but using double quotes as delimiters, and escaping any double quote inside the value with a backslash, should always work.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. I completely forgot about escaping characters and used to remove / from curl code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the double quotes in the Json.
Using single quotes around the Json, and double quotes within will work:

`curl --location "http://localhost:5000/user/signup" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data-raw '{ "name":"Raj Kumar","email":"raj@example.com","password":"samplepassword" }'`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot about escaping characters too.